# JavaScript Debugger

Tags: ide, editor

Does anyone know of a really good editor to debug JavaScript (other then Visual Studio 2008 and FireBug)?
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an article, [Advanced JavaScript Debugging Techniques](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/04/03/advanced-javascript-debugging-techniques/), that describes the use of several tools.  One new tool I learned about that I hadn't heard of before is [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).  Sometimes [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) just immediately shows you your dodgy code that is causing the issue.

Comment: +1 for JSLint! I use it to scrub 3rd party code if it throws errors after being packed.

Comment: I always use jsLint. And it's been getting picker and pickier all along.

Answer (score 5):

Opera has [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/products/dragonfly/), though I still prefer Firebug. Before Firebug there was [Venkman](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/venkman/), though it's future is uncertain at this point.

Answer (score 4):

IE8 beta 2 has a nice debugger

Comment: IE8's debugger is the best I have ever used. And I develop using firebug on a Mac, so thats' saying a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The [Google chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) browser has a reasonable wee JS debugger built-in. There's a good list of the available commands [here](http://www.pascarello.com/lessons/browsers/ChromeDebugHelp.html).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Venkman, the JavaScript debugger for Firefox:

http://www.mozilla.org/projects/venkman/

It's a real source-level javascript debugger where you can set breakpoints and step through code.

Answer (score 2):

[Aptana Studio IDE](http://www.aptana.com/studio) has a nice javascript debugger.

The community version supports only Firefox, the professional one also supports Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

For Internet Explorer debugging (and when you don't have VS 2008), you can use MS Script Editor. This is a good writeup on how to get it configured correctly:

http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/mt/archives/2006/01/howto_debug_jav.html

Answer (score 1):

I work in Aptana. You set breakpoints, hover over variables, and do watches right in the editor. Love it. Never thought I'd move away from Firebug as my chief debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If you're accustomed to using Firebug, you might like [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html), implemented in JavaScript. You can use it as a bookmarklet, which is nice. I'm not sure how powerful it is, I imagine other, "real" solutions are better, but it's handy in a pinch.

Comment: It's not really a debugger. It's more of an inspector.

Comment: Firebug Lite will not load remote scripts, even tho Chrome debugger can. due to being written in javascript.