# What do you use to debug JavaScript besides Firebug?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, browser

What are your favorite JavaScript debugging tools besides Firebug?

Thanks,
Eric

### Duplicate: [JavaScript Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103155/javascript-debugger)

Comment: I thought I had seen something similar before, but couldn't find it via search.

Answer (score 4):

For IE, [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359).

For Opera, [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/).

For cross-browser log output, [Blackbird](http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/) (though it currently has some [CSS class naming issues](http://code.google.com/p/blackbirdjs/issues/detail?id=1) that need to be resolved).

Answer (score 3):

I use the Web Developer extension -- for DOM/CSS stuff, but usually related to JS.  For stuff that works in FF, but not in IE I debug in Visual Studio.  I've also got the Developer Toolbar installed in IE and have the Develop menu turned on in Safari.

**EDIT**: There's also [Venkman](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/venkman/).

Answer (score 2):

alert FTW!!!

Answer (score 1):

[Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) is definitely one that rocks on IE for web development debugging. It's better for DOM inspection and browsing than firebug in my opinion and much less powerful when it comes to javascript.

[Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) also comes with some handy little developer tools, especially for javascript, just use Page Control (the page icon beside address bar) -> Developer and you'll see a javascript debugger there.

[Opera](http://www.opera.com) has yet another developer menu: Tools -> Advanced -> Developer Tools (http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/).

My favorite is a combination of IE developer toolbar for HTML+CSS and Firebug for JavaScript and other stuff that's a little more sophisticated.