# Natural sort of alphanumerical strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, natural-sort

I'm looking for the easiest way to sort an array that consists of numbers and text, and a combination of these.

E.g.,

```
'123asd'
'19asd'
'12345asd'
'asd123'
'asd12'
```

turns into

```
'19asd'
'123asd'
'12345asd'
'asd12'
'asd123'
```

This is going to be used in combination with the solution to [another question I've asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793847/sort-outer-array-based-on-values-in-inner-array-javascript).

The sorting function in itself works, what I need is a function that can say that that '19asd' is smaller than '123asd'.

I'm writing this in JavaScript.

I'm looking for a function for natural sorting.

Comment: see also `How do you do string comparison in JavaScript?` on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165/how-do-you-do-string-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: The original question was asked in 2010, so it wouldn't be surprising :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165/how-to-sort-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: @feeela That's not a natural sort

Answer (score 581, accepted):

This is now possible in modern browsers using [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). By passing the `numeric: true` option, it will smartly recognize numbers. You can do case-insensitive using `sensitivity: 'base'`. It was tested in Chrome, Firefox, and [Internet Explorer 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_11).

Here's an example. It returns `1`, meaning 10 goes after 2:

```
'10'.localeCompare('2', undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'})
```

For performance when sorting large numbers of strings, [the article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) says:

> When comparing large numbers of strings, such as in sorting large arrays, it is better to create an Intl.Collator object and use the function provided by its compare property.

```js
var collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'});
var myArray = ['1_Document', '11_Document', '2_Document'];
console.log(myArray.sort(collator.compare));
```

Comment: If you want to sort an array of objects, you can also use the Collator: https://codepen.io/TimPietrusky/pen/rKzoGN

Comment: To clarify above comment: 
"If the locales argument is not provided or is undefined, the runtime's default locale is used."

Comment: @frodo2975 Here what is undefined parameter here..what is the purpose?

Comment: @Jayden we're passing undefined to avoid having to specify a locale, it will use the browser's default locale.

Comment: If you'll add '01_Document' to your array, it will be placed after '1_Document'. This is wrong. How can we handle that?

Comment: @benshabatnoam In Chrome I'm seeing that numbers with leading 0's are considered equivalent to regular numbers, and are left in their original order if they're equal, which seems like correct behavior to me.

Comment: I don't know what you've checked in Chrome but here is an example from typescript playground you can see...
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAxg9gNnEAXGkC8EB2BTA7hASUyTgDoBheRFMACgFdMATbAMwEscmAaCAb0z0AttjDsoALghIw9bLwDO2TAvZJ2wNQE8pAcgBGIJboC+ASgDcAWABQoSEK0BBMGBBaIGANq6AjAH0AERgoYWUkXV4-AODQkWJIiF0AJiCQsISogAYY9PiIgF1rG1gVeGxSOBgAc1pHFzctUgVUJFpYBGRUUlghAAdwbDNLIA

Comment: @benshabatnoam I looked at your playground, but it's working like I would expect. I see it outputting `["1_Document", "01_Document", "2_Document", "11_Document"]`. The first two documents "1" and "01" are considered equivalent, so they stay in their same order from the input. If you swap them in the input, the output will also be swapped. This is expected behavior from what's called a "stable sort", where if 2 items are equivalent, they stay in the same order.

Answer (score 75):

If you have an array of objects, you can do it like this:

```
myArrayObjects = myArrayObjects.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, {
    numeric: true,
    sensitivity: 'base'
  });
});
```

```js
var myArrayObjects = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "1 example"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "100 example"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "12 example"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "5 example"
  },

]

myArrayObjects = myArrayObjects.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, {
    numeric: true,
    sensitivity: 'base'
  });
});
console.log(myArrayObjects);
```

Answer (score 26):

To compare values you can use a comparing method-

```
function naturalSorter(as, bs){
    var a, b, a1, b1, i= 0, n, L,
    rx=/(\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?)|([^\d.]+)|(\.\D+)|(\.$)/g;
    if(as=== bs) return 0;
    a= as.toLowerCase().match(rx);
    b= bs.toLowerCase().match(rx);
    L= a.length;
    while(i<L){
        if(!b[i]) return 1;
        a1= a[i],
        b1= b[i++];
        if(a1!== b1){
            n= a1-b1;
            if(!isNaN(n)) return n;
            return a1>b1? 1:-1;
        }
    }
    return b[i]? -1:0;
}
```

But for speed in sorting an array, rig the array before sorting,
so you only have to do lower case conversions and the regular expression
once instead of in every step through the sort.

```
function naturalSort(ar, index){
    var L= ar.length, i, who, next, 
    isi= typeof index== 'number', 
    rx=  /(\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?)|([^\d.]+)|(\.(\D+|$))/g;
    function nSort(aa, bb){
        var a= aa[0], b= bb[0], a1, b1, i= 0, n, L= a.length;
        while(i<L){
            if(!b[i]) return 1;
            a1= a[i];
            b1= b[i++];
            if(a1!== b1){
                n= a1-b1;
                if(!isNaN(n)) return n;
                return a1>b1? 1: -1;
            }
        }
        return b[i]!= undefined? -1: 0;
    }
    for(i= 0; i<L; i++){
        who= ar[i];
        next= isi? ar[i][index] || '': who;
        ar[i]= [String(next).toLowerCase().match(rx), who];
    }
    ar.sort(nSort);
    for(i= 0; i<L; i++){
        ar[i]= ar[i][1];
    }
}
```

Comment: would this work in my case, with the inner array deciding the order of the outer one?

Comment: What's `String.prototype.tlc()`?  Is this your own code or did you get it from somewhere?  If the latter, please link to the page.

Comment: sorry about the mistake- corrected, thank you.
If you want a[1] and b[1] to control the sort, use
 a= String(a[1]).toLowerCase();
 b= String(b[1]).toLowerCase();

Comment: I just had a list of data that I wanted to sort, thought it should be easy to do in Chrome Dev Tools console - thanks for the function!

Answer (score 9):

Imagine a number-zero-padding function `n => n.padStart(8, "0")` that takes any number and pads it, i.e.

- "19"  -> "00000019"
- "123" -> "00000123"

This function can be used to help sort the `"19"` string so that it appears before the `"123"` string.

Let's add a regex `/\d+/g` creating the natural expansion function `str => str.replace(/\d+/g, n => n.padStart(8, "0"))` which finds only number sections in a string and pads them, i.e.

- "19asd"  -> "00000019asd"
- "123asd" -> "00000123asd"

Now, we can use this natural expansion function to help implement natural order sort:

```js
const list = [
    "123asd",
    "19asd",
    "12345asd",
    "asd123",
    "asd12"
];

const ne = str => str.replace(/\d+/g, n => n.padStart(8, "0"));
const nc = (a,b) => ne(a).localeCompare(ne(b));

console.log(list.map(ne).sort()); // intermediate values
console.log(list.sort(nc)); // result
```

The intermediate results demonstrated by `list.map(ne).sort()` show what the `ne` natural expansion function does. It implements number-zero-padding on only the number portions of the string and leaves the alphabet components unchanged.

```
[
  "00000019asd",
  "00000123asd",
  "00012345asd",
  "asd00000012",
  "asd00000123"
]
```

The final version of solution implements a natural order comparator `nc` implemented as `(a,b) => ne(a).localeCompare(ne(b))` and uses it in `list.sort(nc)` so things get ordered correctly:

```
[
  "19asd",
  "123asd",
  "12345asd",
  "asd12",
  "asd123"
]
```

Answer (score 6):

The most fully-featured library to handle this as of 2019 seems to be [natural-orderby](https://github.com/yobacca/natural-orderby).

```js
import { orderBy } from 'natural-orderby'

const unordered = [
  '123asd',
  '19asd',
  '12345asd',
  'asd123',
  'asd12'
]

const ordered = orderBy(unordered)

// [ '19asd',
//   '123asd',
//   '12345asd',
//   'asd12',
//   'asd123' ]
```

It not only takes arrays of strings, but it can also sort by the value of a certain key in an array of objects. It can also automatically identify and sort strings of: currencies, dates, currency, and a bunch of other things.

Surprisingly, it's also only 1.6 kB when gzipped.

Comment: Whilst not explicitly stated, your answer appears to be specific to Node.JS.

Comment: @StephenQuan Thanks- I update the answer to use ES6 module syntax which is less NodeJS specific.

Answer (score 2):

Building on [kennebec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings-in-javascript/2802804#2802804) and using the code that [Brian Huisman](http://www.davekoelle.com/files/alphanum.js) & [David koelle](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html) created, here is a modified prototype sorting for an array of objects:

```
//Usage: unsortedArrayOfObjects.alphaNumObjectSort("name");
//Test Case: var unsortedArrayOfObjects = [{name: "a1"}, {name: "a2"}, {name: "a3"}, {name: "a10"}, {name: "a5"}, {name: "a13"}, {name: "a20"}, {name: "a8"}, {name: "8b7uaf5q11"}];
//Sorted: [{name: "8b7uaf5q11"}, {name: "a1"}, {name: "a2"}, {name: "a3"}, {name: "a5"}, {name: "a8"}, {name: "a10"}, {name: "a13"}, {name: "a20"}]

// **Sorts in place**
Array.prototype.alphaNumObjectSort = function(attribute, caseInsensitive) {
  for (var z = 0, t; t = this[z]; z++) {
    this[z].sortArray = new Array();
    var x = 0, y = -1, n = 0, i, j;

    while (i = (j = t[attribute].charAt(x++)).charCodeAt(0)) {
      var m = (i == 46 || (i >=48 && i <= 57));
      if (m !== n) {
        this[z].sortArray[++y] = "";
        n = m;
      }
      this[z].sortArray[y] += j;
    }
  }

  this.sort(function(a, b) {
    for (var x = 0, aa, bb; (aa = a.sortArray[x]) && (bb = b.sortArray[x]); x++) {
      if (caseInsensitive) {
        aa = aa.toLowerCase();
        bb = bb.toLowerCase();
      }
      if (aa !== bb) {
        var c = Number(aa), d = Number(bb);
        if (c == aa && d == bb) {
          return c - d;
        } else {
          return (aa > bb) ? 1 : -1;
        }
      }
    }

    return a.sortArray.length - b.sortArray.length;
  });

  for (var z = 0; z < this.length; z++) {
    // Here we're deleting the unused "sortArray" instead of joining the string parts
    delete this[z]["sortArray"];
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the magic numbers 46, 48, and 57?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to sort an array of objects by multiple fields. After reading a bunch on the topic and some time working with various solutions; I ended up with something I didn't quite see anywhere all in one piece, so figured I'd share it here incase it helps anyone:

```
const orderBy = orders => (a, b) => {
    const sortDirection = { asc: 1, desc: -1 };
    const sortCollator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });
    const totalOrders = orders.length;

    for (let index = 0; index < totalOrders; index++) {
        const { property, direction = 'desc' } = orders[index];
        const directionInt = sortDirection[direction];
        const compare = sortCollator.compare(a[property], b[property]);

        if (compare < 0) return directionInt;
        if (compare > 0) return -directionInt;
    }

    return 0;
};

// Example:

const unsorted = [
    { name: 'Bananas', count: 1 },
    { name: 'Apples', count: 3 },
    { name: 'Bananas', count: 3 },
    { name: 'bananas', count: 2 },
];

const sorted = unsorted.sort(orderBy([{ property: 'name' }, { property: 'count', direction: 'asc' }]));

console.log(sorted);
```