# Natural case sorting in XSL?

Tags: xslt, xpath

Is it possible to do, and how would one achieve, natural case sorting in XSL?

For instance, given the following XML snippet:

```
<items>
  <item>A 24</item>
  <item>B 12</item>
  <item>B 11</item>
  <item>C 10</item>
  <item>A 1</item>
  <item>B 2</item>
</item>
```

How could I sort the output so that I had a list of elements as below?

```
<ul>
  <li>A 1</li>
  <li>A 24</li>
  <li>B 2</li>
  <li>B 11</li>
  <li>B 12</li>
  <li>C 10</li>
</ul>
```

**Edit:** I'm particularly interested in solutions that can work with arbitrary strings, eg. ones that don't follow a common pattern, similar to the way PHP's [natsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `xsl:sort`s:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/items">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item">
        <xsl:sort select="substring-before(., ' ')" />
        <xsl:sort select="substring-after(., ' ')" data-type="number" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<ul>
  <li>A 1</li>
  <li>A 24</li>
  <li>B 2</li>
  <li>B 11</li>
  <li>B 12</li>
  <li>C 10</li>
</ul>
```

More thorough (generic) natural sorting requires a much more involved approach.  Dimitre Novatchev has provided [an XSLT 1.0 approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8352114/1945651) here on Stack Overflow, and another site seems to have [an XSLT 2.0 approach](http://www.mhonarc.org/archive/html/xsl-list/2011-03/msg00003.html). Both are too long to merit reproducing here, so please seek them at those links.

Comment: Is it possible to do this generically, eg. without splitting the string on a space? For instance, if I have a list of files: `200327582_RFTS, 138082008_RFTS, 138012009 RFTS, 10101010, ABCDEF`.

Comment: @unpluggd [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8352114/1945651) is an SO answer by Dimitre Novatchev that appears to be an implementation with a few limitations.  [This](http://www.mhonarc.org/archive/html/xsl-list/2011-03/msg00003.html) appears to be an XSLT 2.0 implementation.