# How to sort an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am not using an associative array. I'm using 1d array like this,

```
array("1,a","5,b","2,c","8,d","6,f");
```

How can I sort this array?

The result should be,

```
array("1,a","2,c","5,b","6,f","8,d");
```

Comment: What problem are you having with [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)? Is the idea to do a numeric sort by the number first, with secondary sort by the following letter? Or just do a standard string sort on the entire text? That is, how do you want to sort `["1,a", "11,a", "2,b", "2,c"]`

Comment: sort() is working.. I made a mistake in my code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [natural sort of text and numbers, JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/natural-sort-of-text-and-numbers-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and assume you want to sort by the number part first, sorting numerically, and then have a secondary lexographic (string) sort on the bit after the comma. That way a value like "11,a" will end up after "2,a" - if you just do a default sort "11,a" will end up before "2,a". So:

```
var a = ["1,a","11,a","8,a","24,z","5,b","2,c","8,d","6,f"];

a.sort(function(a,b) {
   var aparts = a.split(","),
       bparts = b.split(","),
       anum = +aparts[0], // convert first part to number
       bnum = +bparts[0],
       aletter = aparts[1],
       bletter = bparts[1];

   if (anum === bnum)
      return aletter < bletter ? -1 : aletter === bletter ? 0 : -1;
   else
      return anum - bnum;
});
```

Result:

```
["1,a", "2,c", "5,b", "6,f", "8,a", "8,d", "11,a", "24,z"]
```

Comment: Great. I had the similar pblm. I noticed it just now. if the second element is similar then it is not sorting properly. your code helped me. Thanx a lot

Comment: @Anish , Alex handles this far more elegantly... http://stackoverflow.com/a/8652418/555384

Comment: @jondavidjohn - that may be more elegant, but it is not equivalent because it doesn't include a secondary sort on the alpha part.

Answer (score 4):

[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) without a custom sorting function will sort it how you wish (lexicographically).

```
>>> ["1,a","5,b","2,c","8,d","6,f"].sort();
["1,a", "2,c", "5,b", "6,f", "8,d"]
```

Note that this will sort the original array. You can make a shallow copy with `slice()`.

If any of your numbers are larger than `9`, and you want to sort it via the ordinal of the number, you will need a custom sorting function.

```
["1,a","5,b","2,c","8,d","6,f"].sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `array.sort()` built-in JS function. Documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: +1, but I want to advocate MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) over W3Schools. See why http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Dht33/

```
var arrayVar = ["1,a","2,c","5,b","6,f","8,d"];

arrayVar.sort()

arrayVar; // "1,a","2,c","5,b","6,f","8,d"
```

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
function sortNumber(a,b)
{
return (a.split(","))[0] - (b.split(","))[0] ;
}

var n = ["1,a","5,b","2,c","8,d","6,f"];
alert( n.sort(sortNumber) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do:

```
var arr1 = new Array("1,a","5,b","2,c","8,d","6,f");
var arr2 = arr1.sort( function(a, b){
    var ax = a.split(",");
    var bx = b.split(",");
    return ax[0]-bx[0];
});

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = arr2.join(" : ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own comparison function to compare the numbers, otherwise the default `sort()` would put something like `"40,a"` before `"5,b"`.

Here's an example which just splits on the `,` character and assumes the value before it is numerical. I've added `"40,a"` into the example to show that it orders numbers >9 correctly.

```
function mySort(a,b)
{
    return a.split(",", 1) - b.split(",", 1);
}

var theArray = ["1,a", "5,b", "2,c", "40,a", "8,d", "6,f"];
theArray.sort(mySort); // "1,a","2,c","5,b","6,f","8,d","40,a"
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. i think default sort() made a work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
var abc=new Array("1,a","5,b","2,c","8,d","6,f");
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(abc.sort());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var testArray = new Array();
testArray[0] = '1';
testArray[1] = '5';
testArray[2] = '9';
testArray[3] = '8';
testArray[4] = '6';
testArray[5] = '2';
var getlength = testArray.length;
testArray.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
for(var i=0; i<getlength;i++) {         
    alert(testArray[i]);
}
</script>
```