# NodeJS do stuff after fetching all mySql results

Tags: node.js

How to show `'Finish'` after screening all `row.name` results ?

```
npmSql.query("SELECT name FROM sqlTable", function(err, rows, fields) {
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    console.log(row.name);
  });
}, function () { console.log('Finish'); });
```

I was trying to follow some answers like [Node.js - Using the async lib - async.foreach with object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390041/node-js-using-the-async-lib-async-foreach-with-object) but had no luck :(

**Update**

```
function abc() {
    npmSql.query("SELECT name FROM sqlTable", function(err, rows, fields) {
      rows.forEach(function(row) {
        console.log(row.name);
      });
    }, function () { console.log('Finish'); });
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put the `console.log('Finish')` statement after the `forEach` call:

```
npmSql.query("SELECT name FROM sqlTable", function(err, rows, fields) {
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    console.log(row.name);
  });
  console.log('Finish');
});
```

You're using the standard javascript `Array.prototype.forEach`, which is synchronous. The question you linked deals with an unrelated async `foreach` function.

Comment: the npmSql.query is wrapped in a function. Is it possible to return row.name value to that function ? check my updated question