# Node.js - Using the async lib - async.parallel pass an Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have below function which fetches data in parallel. Once the fetching data is done the result will be available via 'results' variable in the callback function. I needs to parameterize instead of hard coding 'products', 'images' etc. I need to be able to pass an array. (i.e I need to say `var fetchInParallel = function (id, res, names)` ) where `names = ['products', 'images']`

How would I do that? I tried [using forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390041/node-js-using-the-async-lib-async-foreach-with-object) with no luck.

```
var fetchInParallel = function (id, res) {

async.parallel(
    [
        function (callback) {
            commonService.findById('products', id, function (result) {
                callback(false, result);
            })
        },

        function (callback) {
            commonService.findById('images', id, function (result) {
                callback(false, result);
            })
        }

    ],

    function (err, results) {
        // handle errors code

        var products = results[0];
        var volatile = results[1];

        var target = stitch(products,images);

        res.send(target)
    }
);
}
```

Comment: How would your result callback look like if it had to deal with dynamic `names`, instead of hardcoded products and volatile images?

Comment: in fact they are dynamic names, the `stich` function will iterate the `results` and stitch the final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`map` function](https://github.com/caolan/async#map):

```
function fetchInParallel(id, names, res) {
    async.map(names, function(name, callback) {
        commonService.findById(name, id, function (result) {
            callback(null, result);
        });
    }, function (err, results) {
        if (err)
            … // handle error code
        var target = stitch(results); // combine names with results
        res.send(target)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use async.map instead of parallel like this;

```
var fetchInParallel = function (id, res,names) {
    async.map(names,
        function (name,callback) {
            commonService.findById(name, id, function (result) {
                callback(null, result);
            })
        },

        function (err, results) {

        }
    );
}
```