# Javascript for loop wait for callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, break

I have this function:

```
function tryStartLocalTrendsFetch(woeid) {
    var userIds = Object.keys(twitClientsMap);
    var isStarted = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < userIds.length; i++) {
        var userId = userIds[i];
        var twitClientData = twitClientsMap[userId];
        var isWoeidMatch = (woeid === twitClientData.woeid);
        if (isWoeidMatch) {

            startLocalTrendsFetch(woeid, twitClientData, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    // Couldn't start local trends fetch for userId: and woeid:
                    isStarted = false;
                } else {
                    isStarted = true;
                }
            });
            // This will not obviously work because startLocalTrendsFetch method is async and will execute immediately
            if (isStarted) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("No users are fetching woeid: " + woeid);
}
```

The gist of this method is that I want the line `if (isStarted) { break; }` to work. The reason is that if it's started it should not continue the loop and try to start another one.

I'm doing this in NodeJS.

Comment: Try looking up the `async` Node package on NPM.

Comment: I'd make i an index variable inside the loop, and change that outer 'for' loop into a while(!isStarted && i<userIds.length). When isStarted=true, the loop falls through and eliminates the need for the 'break'; however, I think there may be other issues with this structure...

Comment: If you're up to refactor your code to avoid callbacks, what @Scimonster said, `async`, will work. I'd recommend Promises, [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) is great. My strongest recommendation would be FRP with [Kefir](https://rpominov.github.io/kefir/).

Answer (score 2):

try to use a recursive definition instead

```
function tryStartLocalTrendsFetch(woeid) {
  var userIds = Object.keys(twitClientsMap);
  recursiveDefinition (userIds, woeid);
}

function recursiveDefinition (userIds, woeid, userIndex)
  var userId = userIds[userIndex = userIndex || 0];
  var twitClientData = twitClientsMap[userId];
  var isWoeidMatch = (woeid === twitClientData.woeid);
  if (isWoeidMatch && userIndex<userIds.length) {
      startLocalTrendsFetch(woeid, twitClientData, function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            recursiveDefinition(userIds, woeid, userIndex + 1)
          } else {
            console.log("No users are fetching woeid: " + woeid);
          }
      });
  } else {
    console.log("No users are fetching woeid: " + woeid);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah smart, I was thinking a recursive method might do the job here :)

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `async` (`npm install async`):

```
var async = require('async');

async.forEach(row, function(col, callback){
    // Do your magic here
    callback();  // indicates the end of loop - exit out of loop
    }, function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
    });
```

More material to help you out: [Node.js - Using the async lib - async.foreach with object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390041/node-js-using-the-async-lib-async-foreach-with-object)