# Callback not getting called while using collection.save() in async foreach loop in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, foreach

My aim is to save records in a mongoDB collection being in a async foreach loop. Below is the code which speaks for itself.

```
async.forEach(data, function(item, callback) {
      var object = new Collection_Object();

      // errorLog.push(sdb);
      object.save(function(error) {
        count++;
        console.log(count);
        if(error) {
          console.log("inside error");
          count--;
        }
        //callback();
      });
      callback();
    }, function() {
    //This is the block which should be called after foreach. 
      res.json(data);
  });
```

Now what is happening is the flow skips the `save` part and directly jumps to the block which should be called after `forEach`.

If i am commenting the `save` part, as expected the callback is working properly. 
I don't see where i am doing mistake. May be `collection.save()` isn't suppose to be like this.
Please guide.

Comment: Might be dup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390041/node-js-using-the-async-lib-async-foreach-with-object

Comment: Why have you commented out the callback() call in save()? That's exactly where it should be called.

Comment: I guess, i kept forgetting to uncomment the below callback() function. It worked. Stupid me.

Answer (score 1):

`object.save()` is also async, so you have to use callback function with save method, like:

```
object.save(function(error) {
        count++;
        console.log(count);
        if(error) {
          console.log("inside error");
          count--;
        }
        callback();
      });
```

Comment: It should be inside the callback passed to `save()`, not passed as a separate argument.