# when should callback be executed

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to log my colors variable after the forEach block completes execution.

As the code stands now it simply returns an empty array. I guess I'm not console.logging at the right moment, but I'm confused about when that should happen.

Basically, what I need is to be able to use my colors array to execute other functions on it. But before I do that I have to make sure that the createParentComponent function finished executing.

Thanks in advance!

```
    var colors = [];

    function createParentComponent(array){
    var count = 0;

    array.forEach(function(image){
       var parent = document.createElement('div');
       parent.style.height = '50px';
       parent.style.width = '50px';
       parent.className = 'parent';

       var imgData = createImgandColorDiv(image);
       var img = imgData[0];
       var cdiv = imgData[1];

       parent.appendChild(img);
       parent.appendChild(cdiv);
       document.getElementById('container').appendChild(parent);
       count ++;
       console.log(count);
    });

    if(count === array.length){console.log(colors);}

}

function createImgandColorDiv(url){
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.style.height = '50px';
    img.style.width = '50px';

    var cdiv=document.createElement('div');
    cdiv.style.height = '50px';
    cdiv.style.width = '50px';
    cdiv.className = 'cdiv';

    img.onload = function(){
        var hsl = getDominantHSLColor(img);
        colors.push(hsl);
        cdiv.style.backgroundColor = 'hsl('+hsl[0]+','+hsl[1]+'%,'+hsl[2]+'%)';
    };

    img.src = url;
    return [img, cdiv]; 
}
```

I was trying to inspire myself from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983138/callback-after-all-asynchronous-foreach-callbacks-are-completed).

Comment: You are shadowing `count` inside of your `forEach` function (it's now pointing at the `cdiv` element).  When you attempt to transform a DOM node into a number it results (rightly) in `NaN`.

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a `count` variable both in `createParentComponent` and the anonymous inner function that you use in `forEach` (`var count = imgData[2];`).

As you can't increment (`++`) whatever ends up being `count` there, you'll get `NaN`.

I'd suggest <del>renaming the inner `count` variable</del> getting rid of the inner `count` variable altogether, since `createImgandColorDiv` only returns two values anyway. :)

Comment: oh, thank you, it's a typo. I was trying different things. I'll rewrite my question then, because now my colors array is logging, but it's empty. Yet I know that that's just because I'm logging it too soon, because when I retry in the browser console, once all images are loaded, I do see the array isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, so adding my conditional to my createImgandColorDiv:

```
function createImgandColorDiv(url){
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.style.height = '50px';
    img.style.width = '50px';

    var cdiv=document.createElement('div');
    cdiv.style.height = '50px';
    cdiv.style.width = '50px';
    cdiv.className = 'cdiv';

    img.onload = function(){
        var c = document.getElementsByClassName('cdiv');
        var hsl = getDominantHSLColor(img);
        colors.push(hsl);
        cdiv.style.backgroundColor = 'hsl('+hsl[0]+','+hsl[1]+'%,'+hsl[2]+'%)';
        if(colors.length===c.length){console.log(colors)};
    };

    img.src = url;
    return [img, cdiv]; 
}
```

I'm open to hear of better ways to write this :)