# Load text from multiple files into multiple divs, then call a function only when all text is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to load text from files into divs using `load()`.

There is a JavaScript function I need to call only when that text has loaded. I know I can use the `load()` callback to do this once one of the text files has loaded, but how to I do this only once all the files have loaded?

This is my attempt using `$.when()`:

```
$.when($("#testdiv").load("text/textures.txt")).done(functio‌​n () { var msg = document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML; alert(msg); });
```

There is a comment below that points to why it is wrong. I need to dig deeper to understand it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback after all asynchronous forEach callbacks are completed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983138/callback-after-all-asynchronous-foreach-callbacks-are-completed)

Comment: Use [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)?

Comment: I tried when() and the function called by when (an alert that displays the div contents) happened before the div had been updated

Comment: `$.when($("#testdiv").load("text/textures.txt")).done(function () {
 var msg = document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML;
 alert(msg);
});`

Comment: I had a look at the link above - forEach callbacks - but it seems specific to processing items in a forEach loop, which I'm not doing

Comment: [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) accepts [deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) while [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) returns `jQuery`, so your code is wrong.

Comment: Anyway, I suggest you to update your question to show how you're doing the `load()`. I'm sure others can more easily answer your question by working on top of your code. You can update your question by clicking on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Pang.  Code added above.  Will investigate deferred objects

Comment: Can you show how you're loading into multiple divs? Are you having multiple divs with the id `testdiv` or are you having another line of code for another div? Are you loading the same file into multiple divs or are you loading different files for each div?

Comment: Why not use the complete callback of load function? [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/) .. Edited: my bad, sorry. Readed your question again, and I saw your problem with the callback.

Comment: How about set an interval timer to check if the divs are empty?  If none  is empty, clear the interval and fire the next function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var loaded = 0;

function callback() {
    loaded++;
    if (loaded === totalNeeded) {
        alldone();
    }
}

function alldone() {
    //do stuff here;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good general solution, it can only handle simple scenarios where there is only one list of elements and the number is stored as a variable scoped to the whole code. It only partially answers the question and has no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend jQuery to add the functionality you want. Here's an example of adding a jQuery method called `loadPromise` which takes either a string url like `.load` does, or a callback which is called for each matching element, which returns the argument to pass to `.load` for that element. It returns a single promise which resolves to an array with one `.load` result per element loaded.

```
// You can pass a single url to be used on all matching elements
// or you can pass a callback, which is called for each
// element in the selector, which returns the url to use
// for that element
$.fn.loadPromise = function(urlOrCallback) {
    var promises = [];
    this.each(function(i, element) {
        var url,
            defer;

        if (typeof urlOrCallback === 'function')
            url = urlOrCallback.call(element, i, element, this);
        else
            url = urlOrCallback;

        if (url) {
            defer = $.Deferred();
            $(element).load(url, function(responseText, textStatus, xhr) {
                defer.resolve({
                    element: element,
                    responseText: responseText,
                    textStatus: textStatus,
                    xhr: xhr
                });
            });
            promises.push(defer.promise());
        }
    });
    return $.when.apply($, promises).then(function(/*...*/) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    });
};

// Simple example:
$('.single-example')
.loadPromise('example-single')
.then(function(result) {
    console.log('done load: ' + result[0]);
});

// Example with multiple
$('.multi-example').loadPromise(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-url');
}).then(function(multi) {
    console.log('multi done', multi);
});
```

Here's a [**live demo** on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcacjeL6/1/). Note that since jsfiddle has gone to great lengths to block this sort of thing, it gets 404 errors (of course, the example names I pass aren't valid URLs), but if you check the console, you'll see it is working as intended. On your own site, it will have no trouble loading if your existing `.load` works.

#### How it works:

JQuery extension functions get the selector passed in `this`. It uses `each` to iterate through each matching element, calling `.load` for that element with the passed url or the result of calling the callback, and creates a promise that is resolved for each one and adding it to the `promises` array.

Once it has its array of promises, it takes that and uses `apply` to pass multiple parameters to `$.when`, one for each element. `$.when` returns a promise which is resolved when all of the promises are resolved. The `.then` for the promise `$.when` returns receives multiple parameters, one per promise. The `.then` handler there takes all of the parameters and makes one array from them all, and returns it, resolving the promise returned from `loadPromise` with a single parameter, an array of completions.

Run the fiddle and have a look at the debugger console. You'll see that the promise loadPromise returns is resolved with an array, click into them and have a look at what it returns. You probably don't need that much detailed information, just the promise being resolved at all tells you that they all finished loading.

#### Side note

Most jQuery APIs that can work on multiple elements have an overload where you can pass a function, and give it a value to use for an argument for each element, as I did in my extension. For example, `.text` can work on a selector that matches multiple elements, getting the text for each element by calling your callback. Apparently, they forgot to do this for `.load`. Additionally, jQuery has a mechanism for waiting for multiple completions, which is used for waiting for multiple animations. They seem to have forgotten about that with `.load` as well.