# Javascript : function not async are not call in the right order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have this : https://jsfiddle.net/ahhc9tjn/

The problem is about this two functions :

```
this.addShipTest1 = function() {
    this.revolutionTime += 0.5;
    this.stopAllShipCSS();
    this.addShip()
}

this.addShipTest2 = function() {
    this.revolutionTime += 0.5;
    this.stopAllShipCSS();

    var save = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        save.addShip();
    }, 100);
}
```

Why do I have to wait to make this work ? I mean the functions are not asynchronous, so should

```
addShip()
```

Be call only after

```
stopAllShipCSS()
```

The problem is that, in addShipTest1, the stop is "call after" or "ignore"... (The JSFiddle show the problem).

Edit :

Solutions I tried, but that doesn't succeed :

```
(1)
$.when(this.stopAllShipCSS()).then(this.addShip());

(2)
var it = 0;
var save = this;
this.ships.forEach(function(ship) {
  ship.css({
    'animation':''
  });
  it++;
  if (it == save.ships.length) {
    save.addShip();
   }
});
```

Comment: it's because they *are* asynchronous

Comment: Can you show us what stopAllShipCSS() does?
I get this all the time when I use Kendo,  I think some of Kendo's calls are async.

Comment: which one ? and I tried to use this property $.when(this.stopAllShipCSS()).then(this.addShip()) but it doesn't work either

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Your explanation is not really clear. What happens, and what is it that you expect to happen?

Comment: The JSFiddle show the problem (click mutiple time on 'add ship' button), the first that is not using 'setTimeout' doesn't work... but i wan't him to work because there's not evident reason (for me) to wait 100 ms...

Comment: Take a look here. It will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983138/callback-after-all-asynchronous-foreach-callbacks-are-completed

Comment: No, the fiddle does not show the problem. If I add a `console.log()` in `stopAllShipCSS()`, it always happens *before* `addShip()` is called.

Comment: [Here is an update to the fiddle with added `console.log()` calls.](https://jsfiddle.net/ahhc9tjn/1/)

Comment: (1) I tried this Steeve, but doesn't work...
(2) This is why i'm confuse

Comment: @ThomasPetillot have you looked at the updated jsfiddle that I mentioned? I don't see any problem with the code. The `stopAllShipCSS()` function **is** called before `addShip()` and it finishes before `addShip()`.

Comment: Yes, thats what I said i was confuse... Because, if this order of call is good, the two function should give the same result, but they didn't ...

Comment: I really can't found why i'm not doing right...