# How To jQuery Post inside Each and work with result after Each end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code

```
function getSomeInfoFromDB() {
    let body = "";
    let text = "";
    $("tr").each(function (index) {
        let code = $(this).children("td:nth-child(2)");
        $.post("http://urltogetdatafromdatabase.com/getinfo.php", {a: code}).done(function (data) {
            text = "<dvi>" + index + " " + data + "</div>";
        });
        body = body + text;
    });

    let bigboody = "<div class='outer'>" + body + "</div>";
    doSomethingWithResult(bigboody);
}
```

But doSomethingWithResult() always work before $post return me data
How can I do this work fine?

In result I need

```
  <div class='outer'>
  <div> 1 data text from database</div>
  <div> 2 next text from database</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Posible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983138/callback-after-all-asynchronous-foreach-callbacks-are-completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to move `doSomethingWithResult()` inside of your `done()` function, since `post()` is async.

```
function getSomeInfoFromDB(){
  let body= "";
  let text = "";

  $("tr").each(function(){
    let code = $(this).children("td:nth-child(2)");
    $.post( "http://urltogetdatafromdatabase.com/getinfo.php", { a: code })
      .done(function(data) {
        text = "<div>"+data+"</div>";
        body = body + text;

        let bigboody = "<div class='outer'>"+body+"</div>";
        doSomethingWithResult(bigboody);
      });
    });
}
```

But note that `post()` in an `each()`, they may return in different orders, which since you're appending them, may not be what you want.

The safer approach (where you can control the order), is to use `Promise.all()` and gather the `post()` calls up as promises and into an array. Something like this:

```
function getSomeInfoFromDB(){
  let promises = [];

  $("tr").each(function(){
    let code = $(this).children("td:nth-child(2)");
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve) => 
      $.post( "http://urltogetdatafromdatabase.com/getinfo.php", { a: code }).done(resolve)
    ))
  });

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(datas => '<div>' + datas.join('</div><div>') + '</div>') // easy way to wrap all of them in divs and put them together
    .then(body => doSomethingWithResult('<div class="outer">' + body + '</div>');
}
```

Basically, you wrap each `post()` up as a `Promise` and put that `Promise` in an array. Then, use `Promise.all()` which will run when all of the promises are finished. The `then()` for that will give you an array of results, one for each post, in order. You can then do whatever you want with them at that point.

Comment: In this case .then(datas and .then(body new variables?

Comment: Looks like promise is the best way to do this

Comment: Yeah. You can do it in one `.then()`, but I think it's cleaner with two. The first gets an array of the results of all of your posts (each element is one result). Joining that into a string gives the equivalent of your `body`. If you return that from the first then, it'll be the input for the second then, giving you a fairly clean look.

Answer (score 0):

Your `done function` is a call back function of post. It's called after receiving data from your server side. So, `doSomethingWithResult` is calling before your `done function` You need to call your `doSomethingWithResult` function in the callback

```
function getSomeInfoFromDB(){
    let body= "";
    let text = "";
    $("tr").each(function(index){
    let code = $(this).children("td:nth-child(2)");
    $.post( "http://urltogetdatafromdatabase.com/getinfo.php", { a: code     }).done(function( data ){
        text = "<dvi>"+index+" "+data+"</div>";
        let bigboody = "<div class='outer'>"+body+"</div>";
        doSomethingWithResult(bigboody);
    });
    body = body + text;
    });


}
```

Comment: Problem is the problem is that
I need in result < div.outer >< div> 1 div with text< /div>< div> 2 div with text< /div> < /div >
NOT
< div.outer >< div> 1 div with text< /div>< /div >
< div.outer >< div> 2 div with text< /div> < /div >

Answer (score 0):

If you need all data to be executed in that order, your already have other answers.

If you don't care abour order, but must wait until all is done, you can count calls and wait until last one is done, like this

```
function getSomeInfoFromDB()
{
    let body = "";
    let text = "";
    var waiting=0;

    $("tr").each(function (index) {
        let code = $(this).children("td:nth-child(2)");
        waiting++;
        $.post("http://urltogetdatafromdatabase.com/getinfo.php", {a: code}).done(function (data) {
            text = "<dvi>" + index + " " + data + "</div>";
            waiting--;
            if (waiting==0)
            {
                let bigboody = "<div class='outer'>" + body + "</div>";
                doSomethingWithResult(bigboody);
            }

        });
        body = body + text;
    });
}
```