# API call and callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, callback

I am trying to create a route that makes 2 API calls, the second depends on the results from the first one and only needs to be called if certain criteria are met. Below are the problems I am having.

1. The finalCheck function seems to get called before the forEach no matter what? Even when wrapped in the if statement
2. The counter and userNamesAvailable are not available out of the scope 
   they are assigned in.
3. I am sure there is a better way to do this and would love any relevant 
   advice.

   ```
   router.post('/namecheck', async function(req, res, next) {   
     var name = req.body.name;
     var counter = 0
     var domains = []
     var userNamesAvailable = []
     var dotcom = true
     var answer = ''

   getDomains(checkDomains)

   // Check domain availabilty
   function getDomains (callback) {
     var url='https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1/domains/available?checkType=FAST'
     Unirest.post(url)
       .headers({
         "Authorization" : "sso-key ",
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
       })
       .send(
         [
           name + '.com',
           name + '.net',
           name + '.org'
         ]
       )
       .end(function(response) { 
         domains=response.body.domains
         console.log(domains)
         callback(domains)
       })

   }
    function checkDomains(domains) {
      var d = 0

   //If no data is returned send error
   if(!domains) 
   {
     console.log("No data returned")
     return next("No data returned")
   } else {
     //Check how many domains are unavailable
     for(var i=0; i < domains.length; i++) {
       if(domains[i].available == false){
         d = d + 1
         //Flag if the .com is available
         if(domains[i].domain == name + '.com') {
           dotcom = false
         }
       }
     }

     if (d >2) {
       console.log("d is greater than 1")
       answer = 'no'
     //If 2 domains are available and one is .com continue
     } else if (d>1 && dotcom =='false') {
       answer = 'no'
     }
   }
   getUsernames(finalCheck)
   }

   function getUsernames(callback){
     // Social Sites to Check
     var sitenames = [ 
       'facebook',
       'twitter',
       'instagram',
       'youtube',
       'slack',
       'blogger'
     ]

     // Check Usename availabitliy
     let i = 0
     sitenames.forEach(sitename => {

     Unirest.post('https://api.namechk.com/services/check.json')
     .headers({
       'AUTHORIZATION': 'Bearer ',
       'Accept': 'application/vnd.api.v1+json',
     }).send({
       'site': sitename, username: name,
     }).end(function(response) { 
       if(response.body.available == false){
         counter ++
       } else {
         userNamesAvailable.push(response.body)
       }
     });
     i++
   });
   console.log(counter)
   console.log(userNamesAvailable)
   if(i == sitenames.length){
     callback(counter, dotcom)
    }
   }

   function finalCheck(counter, dotcom) {
     console.log('Start finalCheck')
     console.log(counter)
     console.log(dotcom)
       //Final Check for is a name is a go or not
       //If one social site is not available and the 
       if(counter == 1 && dotcom =='true') {
         console.log(5-counter + ' social sites available')
         res.send("yes");
       } else {
         res.send("no")
       }
     }
    })
   ```

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue but you have `d > 1 & dotcom == 'false'` and perhaps you meant `d > 1 && dotcom == false` (ie, change & to && and change 'false' to false). Same changes for finalCheck.

Comment: the callback on `getUsernames` happens before the `forEach` because each of those elements creates an asyncronous call. You need to watch that *all* of those requests end before calling the callback.

Comment: Thanks I did catch that conditional but it is not affecting the other code.  I realize why the getUsernames getting called but not sure how to structure it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983138/callback-after-all-asynchronous-foreach-callbacks-are-completed). You should be able to do it using `Promise`.

You have to change only the function `getUsernames`.

```
  function getUsernames(callback) {
    // Social Sites to Check
    var sitenames = [
      'facebook',
      'twitter',
      'instagram',
      'youtube',
      'slack',
      'blogger'
    ];

    // Check Usename availabitliy
    let requests = sitenames.map((sitename) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        Unirest.post('https://api.namechk.com/services/check.json')
          .headers({
            'AUTHORIZATION': 'Bearer ',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.api.v1+json',
          }).send({
            'site': sitename,
            username: name,
          }).end(function(response) {
            if (response.body.available == false){
              counter++;
            } else {
              userNamesAvailable.push(response.body);
            }
            resolve();
          });
      });  
    });

    Promise.all(requests).then(() => { 
      console.log(userNamesAvailable);
      callback(counter, dotcom);
    });
  }

  function finalCheck() {
    console.log('Start finalCheck')
    console.log(counter)
    console.log(dotcom)
    //Final Check for is a name is a go or not
    //If one social site is not available and the
    if (counter == 1 & dotcom == 'true') {
      console.log(5 - counter + ' social sites available')
      res.send("yes");
    } else {
      res.send("no")
    }
  }
```

Remember that asyncronous functions in `javascript` are a feature and not something you should be fighting (what I think you are trying to do declaring your main function as `async function`). Try to understand them first and you will notice they are a big advantage.

There is plenty of documentation about them out there...
[async Fucntion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
[understanding Promises](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-promises-in-javascript-13d99df067c1)

EDIT: Do not send the variables that you call *global* as parameters, they are already available in the called function.

Comment: Thanks!  So I am still wondering why the userNamesAvailable and counter are not available globally?  Everything else seems to be working.

Comment: I will edit my answer to handle your logs of `userNamesAvailable` and increment the counter on each `Unirest.end`, you should see the logs working correctly.

Comment: That would work also, I am actually counting the false responses and saving the true ones.  I had my code as above but counter and userNamesAvailable are still not available.

Comment: How do you know they are not available?

Comment: The console.log for userNamesAvailable is always [] except inside the loop

Comment: It is because you are sending it as a parameter to `finalCheck`, I will update my answer to include that change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182828/discussion-between-byrdemmanuel-and-rsteen76).