# Is foreach guaranted to loop in the same order everytime over the same data set?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, iteration, sequence

Is foreach (`Array.prototype.forEach`) guaranted to loop in the same order every time over the same data set? And why?

Comment: What loop and what object?

Comment: Because `forEach` is not asynchronous? It takes next argument only if the previous iteration has finished. And of course if you are not calling any asynchro function in that loop.

Comment: Do you mean `Array.prototype.forEach`? And what do you mean by *"why"*?

Comment: Sure, but if the function supplied to it does some asynchronous processing with the value, there is no guarantee that that processing happens in any particular order.  `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach((n) => setTimeout(() => console.log(n), Math.random() * 1000))`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean I wanted to understand what's behind the order logic in either case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the implementation is sticking to the standard then yes, `forEach` processes the array in order except for sparse arrays where uninitialized values are ignored. `forEach()` is described in [the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18):

> forEach calls callbackfn once for each element present in the array, in ascending order. callbackfn is called only for elements of the array which actually exist; it is not called for missing elements of the array.

It loops through the index starting with:

> Let lenValue be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with the argument "length"
>   Let k be 0.
>   Repeat, while k < len
>   ...
>   Increase k by 1

In javascript Arrays *are* objects and have a `length` property and integer keys which are the indexes. The spec is saying it will start at `k=0` and call the `arr[k]` in increasing order for `k < length`. It will call the callback for all values where `arr` has a property `k`

An example of a sparse array where `forEach` ignores elements might look like this:

```js
let a  = Array(10)
a[5] = "Five"
a[9] = "Nine"
console.log(a)
// ignores initialized values:
a.forEach((item) => console.log(item))
```

If you are doing asynchronous things inside the callback, it can appear that the callback is not happening in order, but it still is.

*EDIT based on comment:*

You can with a little hacking pass an object to `forEach` that looks like an array (it has a length and integer keys). `forEach` will call the items in *index* order, not the order they are defined on the object. For example:

```js
// an object that has enough info
// for forEach to use
let o = {
    3: "three",
    2: "two",
    0: "zero",
    1: "one",

    length: 4
}

// calls in order of indexes, not order keys were defined
Array.prototype.forEach.call( o, (i) => console.log(i))
```

Comment: does it really loop  "in ascending order"  or according to the order in wich each elements of the object has been define

Comment: @Xsmael see the edit for an edge case example. `forEach` calls in ascending order of key which in the case of arrays is the index.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, forEach will wait for the previous item to complete before processing the next one

```
//Sync methods;
[1,2,3].forEach(function(e){
    console.log(e)
});
//Output:
//1
//2
//3
```

If you're using **Async methods** inside the loop, **they will be called in order but the loop will not wait for the callback.**

```
//Async Methods
[1,2,3].forEach(function(e){
    someAsyncMethod(e, console.log);
});
//Output example:
//3
//1
//2
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18983245/4511735) have some methods to use async functions inside foreach.

As for *why*, there is an international standard called **ECMAScript** all JavaScript implementations should adhere to it; the behaviour of `Array.prototype.forEach()` is specified in this standard.

You cand find the specification and the pseudo-code for `Array.prototype.forEach()` at [ECMAScript® 2018 Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.foreach)