# Return in method just showing undefined. How to get the callback?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a method with a forEach loop.

This works fine and shows a result list.

Here is the code:

```
test() {

  os.cpus().forEach(el => {
    if (el.model.search('Intel') === 0) {
      return el.model.match(/i(.*)-/)[1];
    }
  });

}
```

The forEach has a return and the method return undefined.

I know I need to do a `callback` but I just don't know how to do this in this code.

How can I get `test()` to return the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback after all asynchronous forEach callbacks are completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983138/callback-after-all-asynchronous-foreach-callbacks-are-completed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.find` instead, and if a match is found, perform the `.match(` operation:

```
test() {
  const foundEl = os.cpus().find((el) => el.model.search('Intel') === 0);
  if (foundEl) {
    return foundEl.model.match(/i(.*)-/)[1];
  }
}
```

Since it looks like `el.model` is a string, better to use `startsWith` than `.search`:

```
test() {
  const foundEl = os.cpus().find((el) => el.model.startsWith('Intel'));
  if (foundEl) {
    return foundEl.model.match(/i(.*)-/)[1];
  }
}
```

You generally have to use callbacks for *asynchronous* operations. With synchronous operations (such as this one), you can simply `return` the value.

Comment: os.cpus()  doesn't have a property "find"

Comment: It's still returning undefined

Comment: os.cpus() returns an array, so how could it not have a "find" method exactly?

Comment: @Charlie It doesn't? I thought [`The os.cpus() method returns an array of objects containing information about each logical CPU core.`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_cpus)?

Comment: @KevinPorche It will return `undefined` if no elements fulfilled the `.find` test.

Comment: it does but you have to extract it first as Kenvin states, is returning undefined

Comment: @Charlie The `foundEl` will containing the extracted CPU object, if a matching one is found. What further extraction are you describing?

Comment: lol you're right, it seems the reason he still gets undefined is because his processor is not intel