# Why the code does "new Promise" always result in empty array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

this is my Html5 code :

```
<div>
    <input type="file" multiple (change)="comPress($event.target.files)">
</div>
```

i need on change do this function comPress() with all files.
this is in Angular component.ts :

```
comPress(images){
   function fetchResult(img) {
    return new Promise(  function(resolve, reject) {

      let data = [];
      for(let i of img){
      var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          data = [...data, e.target['result']];
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(i);
      }

       resolve(data);
       reject('reject');
    })

  };

  fetchResult(images).then(data=>{
    console.log(data) // is always []
  }).catch(err=>console.log(err))

}
```

i need  push this variable `let data = [];` with all result data from function `onload()`

but the result is always `[]` empty array!

I expect this result :

```
["data:sadvdsbdsbdsvdsvdsbdb", "data:vaswbvewbewbregergreg"]
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: You resolve the promise *outside* the asynchronous operation?

Comment: how do this with input file ? is not working outside the ```comPress()```

Comment: I would suggest creating an array of promises and using `Promise.all` to combine them. Or using `async/await`. Or do something like the answers to [Callback after all asynchronous forEach callbacks are completed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18983138/215552)...

Comment: Why are you rejecting the promise immediately after resolving it?

Comment: The whole point of the promise executor with its callback arguments is that you can call `resolve` after the asynchronous stuff happened - in the `onload` listener.

Answer (score 1):

After the loop ends, your `onload` handlers are still not run. So data is not populated. What you can do first is this:

```js
function readFile(i) {
  return new Promise(success => {  
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => {
      success(e.target['result']);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(i);
  });
}
```

You get a promise that resolves with the actual data from `FileReader`. Then in your main code:

```js
return Promise.all(img.map(i => readFile(i)));
```

Comment: Don't forget to install an error handle as well.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is that promise is resolved before on load event is called thus  resulting in empty array what you need to do is resolve your promise in onloadend event i.e

```
reader.onloadend = function() {
  resolve(data)
}
```