# Why JavaScript [].forEach(() => {}); callback is blocking the next line to be executed

Tags: javascript

Since JavaScript is single threaded environment and there is Event Loop which is executing all the queued tasks, then why is `[].forEach(() => {});` not executed asynchronously?

```
console.log("1");
[2].forEach(value => console.log(value));
console.log("3");
```

Output: 1 2 3

Why output will not be 1 3 2

Why callback function within `.forEach` method is blocking the next line of code.

Comment: Why did you expect otherwise? `forEach` is synchronous. If it was asynchronous, you should expect `3 1 2` anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Callback after all asynchronous forEach callbacks are completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983138/callback-after-all-asynchronous-foreach-callbacks-are-completed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.forEach()` doesn't queue tasks to be executed on future event loops, it executes each function immediately, in the current event loop.

This is the default behavior of most functions in javascript as it's a synchronous language. If you require asynchronous behavior, you have to opt into it using things like `setTimeout` and natively asynchronous functions (mostly file i/o and network requests).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a synchronous language. It will not execute a piece of code until the code before it has been executed.

There are ways to get around it for example you could use a `setTimeout` function to wait a few moments before executing the forEach loop and you would then see the result `1, 3, 2`.