# Execute conditional statement after loop finishes in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, async.js

I have a for loop for checking multiple uploaded image's aspect ratio, after completing the loop i want to check ratio in if else condition to redirect user. Problem is the conditions are checked before loop finishes, I need the loop to be completed before checking conditions. I found out async whilst might be suitable here but i'm confused about the best approach for implemetation, can anyone give me workaround to perform the code sequentially.

```
//check image ratio         
var validImageRatio = true;
for(i=0; i<req.files.propertyPhoto.length; i++){
    
    var tempFile = req.files.propertyPhoto[i].tempFilePath.replace(/\\/g, '/');
    var ratio;var width;var height;
    var acceptedRatio = 3;
    
    //get image ratio
    sizeOf(tempFile, function (err, dimensions) {
        width = dimensions.width;
        height = dimensions.height;
        ratio = width/height;
    });
    if (ratio < (acceptedRatio - 0.1) || ratio > (acceptedRatio + 0.1)) {
        validImageRatio = false;
        break;
    }
}
//if ratio invalid, redirect
if (!validImageRatio) {
    ...
}
//if ratio valid, upload
else{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Callback after all asynchronous forEach callbacks are completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983138/callback-after-all-asynchronous-foreach-callbacks-are-completed)

Comment: The `sizeOf` function runs asynchronously so node continues on before the `width`/`height`/`ratio` values are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing the check asynchronously, the synchronous code will run first. If you use async/await inside the for loop, it will block each iteration of the loop making it run slower. The approach you can go for is to use `Promise.all` to run the checks concurrently.

```js
const promises = req.files.propertyPhoto.map(prop => new Promise(resolve => {
    const tempFile = prop.tempFilePath.replace(/\\/g, '/');
    const acceptedRatio = 3;

    // get image ratio
    sizeOf(tempFile, function (err, dimensions) {
        const width = dimensions.width;
        const height = dimensions.height;
        const ratio = width / height;
        if (ratio < (acceptedRatio - 0.1) || ratio > (acceptedRatio + 0.1)) {
            return resolve(false);
        }
        resolve(true);
    });
}));

const result = await Promise.all(promises);

if (result.some(r => r === false)) {
    // if any of the ratio is invalid, redirect

} else {
    // else upload
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at what you mean, but a for-loop would complete before checking the conditions at the bottom except that you include a "break" statement. The break statement makes the for-loop stop executing and move on.