# Asynchronous foreach or for loop in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, node-async

I'm at beginner level of NodeJs, so kindly excuse. Following lambda function is to zip/compress files in S3 and upload the compressed file back to S3. `listOfKeys` contains list of keys to be zipped. If you notice `for (const file in listOfKeys)`, this runs synchronously resulting lambda to timeout if there is a large dataset, i.e if `listOfKeys` has long list of keys. Questions is, is there a way to run the loop asynchronously or parallelly, so that files are zipped in timely manner or asynchronously?

Code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const async = require('async');
const archiver = require('archiver');
const stream = require('stream');
const request = require('request');

const awsOptions = {
    region: 'us-east-1'
};
const s3 = new AWS.S3(awsOptions);

const streamTo = (bucket, key) => {
    var passthrough = new stream.PassThrough();
    s3.upload({
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
        Body: passthrough,
        ContentType: "application/zip",
    },
        (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        }
    );
    return passthrough;
};

const getStream = (bucket, key) => {
    let streamCreated = false;
    const passThroughStream = new stream.PassThrough();

    passThroughStream.on("newListener", event => {
        if (!streamCreated && event == "data") {
            const s3Stream = s3
                .getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: key })
                .createReadStream();
            s3Stream
                .on("error", err => passThroughStream.emit("error", err))
                .pipe(passThroughStream);

            streamCreated = true;
        }
    });
    return passThroughStream;
};

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    let totalKeys = 0;
    const listOfKeys = [];
    const SrcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const trigger_file = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    const prefix = trigger_file.split('/')[0] + '/' + trigger_file.split('/')[1] + '/';
    const dirToZip = trigger_file.split('/')[2].substr(0, trigger_file.split('/')[2].length - '.renamed'.length);
    const s3ListFilter = prefix + dirToZip;
    const destinationKey = prefix + `${dirToZip}.zip`;
    const bucketParams = {
        Bucket: SrcBucket,
        Delimiter: '/',
        Prefix: s3ListFilter + '/'
    };

    let data;
    do {
        bucketParams.Marker = (data && data.NextMarker) ? data.NextMarker : undefined;
        data = await s3.listObjects(bucketParams).promise();
        const contents = data.Contents;
        totalKeys = totalKeys + contents.length;
        listOfKeys.push(...contents.map(x => x.Key));
    } while (data.IsTruncated);

    console.log(`Total keys: ${listOfKeys.length}`);
    
    await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        var zipStream = streamTo(SrcBucket, destinationKey);
        zipStream.on("close", resolve);
        zipStream.on("end", resolve);
        zipStream.on("error", reject);
        var archive = archiver("zip");
        archive.on("error", err => {
            throw new Error(err);
        });
        archive.pipe(zipStream);

        var keysCounter = 0;
        listOfKeys.forEach(file => {
            archive.append(getStream(SrcBucket, file), { name: file.split('/')[3] })
            keysCounter++
            if (keysCounter >= Object.keys(listOfKeys).length) {
                // Called at the end of the loop
                archive.finalize();
            }
        });

        //archive.finalize();
    }).catch(err => {
        throw new Error(err);
    });

    callback(null, {
        body: { final_destination: destinationKey }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### Array.prototype.forEach()

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array1.forEach(element => console.log(element));

// expected output: "a"
// expected output: "b"
// expected output: "c"
```

So your code should be :

```js
listOfKeys.forEach(file => {
    archive.append(getStream(SrcBucket, listOfKeys[file]), { name: listOfKeys[file].split('/')[3] })
})
```

(Not sure if it works though, let me know)

Source : [Array.prototype.forEach() | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

#### Edit :

so `archive.finalize()` should be called after the loop ended, there are several way to do it but I think this one should work fine. See : [Callback after all asynchronous forEach callbacks are completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983138/callback-after-all-asynchronous-foreach-callbacks-are-completed)

```js
//There's probably a better way to do it but it works :
keysCounter = 0
listOfKeys.forEach(file => {
    archive.append(getStream(SrcBucket, listOfKeys[file]), { name: listOfKeys[file].split('/')[3] })
    keyCounter++
    if(keyCounter >= Object.keys(listOfKeys).length) {
        // Called at the end of the loop
        archive.finalize();
    }
})
```

Comment: @Aniruddha I think this is due to the archive.finalize(), let me edit my answer

Comment: Ok, so where that should be placed?

Comment: @Aniruddha Haven't tried but I think it should work now

Comment: I appreciate your talent and work, however this also doesn't seem to be working. Lambda timed out. :(

Comment: @Aniruddha That's sad, you might try to add more part of your code under [// Called at the end of the loop] such as [callback()] but otherwise I don't know how to help more

Comment: Thanks for your help again, I've updated the entire code.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably rewrite the whole thing more agressively, but to answer your specific question:  replace your `listOfKeys.forEach` statement with this:

```js
await Promise
  .all(
    listOfKeys.map(key => archive.append(getStream(SrcBucket, key), { name: key.split('/')[3] }))
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. However, the code is still running synchronously. Lambda still times out

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to do them within one lambda function, offset them using SQS, having a separate lambda to process each zip.

That way, you can isolate the following:

- Failures between each zip archive
- Run each zip process in parallel
- Isolate processing per zip in a single lambda function
- Implement a dead letter queue for messages (or zips) that cannot be handled
- Creates SRP (single responsibility) within your application i.e. one lambda take the zip file and another to process it

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I shall try that, since I'll have to study about SQS