# Load multiple JSON files

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am working on a project with node.js, where there are multiple JSON files in a folder say FILES and I have to access contents of the files. 
One approach is to use

```
var a = require('jsonfile')
```

And then perform the required queries.

But suppose if I have around 20 files, it would be a headache to write them all with the require function, is there a better way to do this. I know Mongodb can be used in this case, but I want to be to use JSON files. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10049704/3556874

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var data = {},
    dir = __dirname + '/FILES/';
fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(function (file) {
    data[file.replace(/\.json$/, '')] = require(dir + file);
});
```

Then for example you can access a json file named `config.json` with `data.config`.

You can also use [`require-dir` module](https://github.com/aseemk/requireDir) like this to do the same:

```
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
var data = requireDir(__dirname + '/FILES/');
```

Comment: Getting an error on this line says unexpected token on the '.' before the forEach. fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(function (file) {

Comment: @pkoli I doubt the fact you are running the same code as above. I can't reproduce the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use something like this?

[How do you get a list of the names of all files present in a directory in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/getting-all-filenames-in-a-directory-with-node-js)

Write all the filenames in an array and then loop over it.

Or you could write an index-file with all the current files and read that first.