# How to get all files path from directory in node.js

Tags: node.js, file

I'm working on retrieve images from csv file.
Right now, i could manage.

- retrieve data base64 images from a csv file
- convert base64 image & export it as a .jpeg files in a directory

which the directory is like this

```
├── assets
    ├── export
        ├── img1.jpeg
        ├── img2.jpeg
        ├── img3.jpeg
        ├── ...
```

how do i get all imgs path from the export directory?.

Comment: you can use [_dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well looking at the [node doc](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) is like this.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const dirnameExportImg = './assets/export'

fs.readdir(dirnameExportImg, function (err, files) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  files.map(
    (file) => { console.log(file) }
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this post might by usefull for you
[StackOverflow - Reading all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049557/reading-all-files-in-a-directory-store-them-in-objects-and-send-the-object)

First answer describes very good how to iterate over multiple files in directory and get them stored into object.

Comment: hi, i read it before made my post, but it was to op for what i was looking for, also is a great post that worth chek it.