# Sending and receiving data with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express server running that sends an html file from the public folder of my project. It is from a client script linked from this html file that I am trying to request and send data to the server. I have looked just about everywhere and have had no luck finding a way to do this. I thought that it could be done just using express but I cannot seem to figure it out. I feel like I must be missing or misunderstanding something obvious. How can I do this?

```
|--index.js
|--template.json
|--public
|  |--index.html
|  |--client.js
```

> **1:** Here is my file structure. I am trying to have client.js send a request to index.js which then will respond with some json.

Any solutions or even just pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into Ajax and fetch API?

Comment: I looked into AJAX but haven't heard of, and will have to look into, fetch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple setup:

1) Express serves `index.html` from `public/` folder which executes `client.js`

2) We have an Express route which reads the `template.json` file and loads it in a route at `/json/`

3) The `client.js` does an Ajax request via `fetch()`, hits the `/json/` route, which serves the JSON content to the browser script

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const data = require("./template.json");

app.use( express.static( __dirname + '/public' ) );

app.get("/json", (req,res)=>{
    // Send a JSON response with the data from template.json
    res.json( data );
})

app.listen( 8080 );
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Express</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Express</h1>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**client.js**

```
// Make an HTTP request to the /json/ route of our express server:
fetch("/json")
// Get the request body and convert to JSON:
.then((res)=> res.json())
// Here we have the request body as a JSON object ready to be used:
.then((data)=>{

    console.log( data );

})
.catch(console.error);
```

**template.json**

```
{"firstname":"john","lastname":"doe"}
```

References:

- [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: If I were to then create a folder with multiple json files in it would I have to require each file individually or could I require an entire folder?

Comment: Yes, you must require each file individually, through some kind of loop. @kevinuulong Maybe these will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049557/reading-all-files-in-a-directory-store-them-in-objects-and-send-the-object