# Read all .md files, convert them to html and send them

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs, readfile

I use `fs` to read the file which is in .md format and I want to transform it into html file.

This is my code so far:

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/posts/react-v16.13.0.md', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(data);
});
```

the file is situated in that folder and has that name.

This function puts in console the content of the .md file.

For converting it to html I added this:

```
const showdown = require('showdown');
converter = new showdown.Converter();
...
fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/posts/react-v16.13.0.md', 'utf8', function (
  err,
  data
) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  text = data;
  html = converter.makeHtml(text);
  console.log(html);
});
```

It puts the file as html in the log which is fine.

My problem is how to do this if there are multiple files in `/posts/` folder, how to read and send those files?

I would like to send them to front-end using a POST method.

Is it possible to read all the files from the folder, transform them and send them?

Comment: You can use `fs.readdir()` to obtain a list of files. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback

Comment: @AKX I tried something like `fs.readdir(__dirname + '/posts', 'utf8', function (err, data) { ...}` but I get his error: `/.../Projects/md/server/node_modules/showdown/dist/showdown.js:2459
    text = text.replace(/¨/g, '¨T');
`

Comment: This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10049704/1524756

Comment: What do you mean by "all files ... send them". Concat them all to a single html blob and send it as response/request body?

Comment: You lost me, sorry , : blush:

Comment: where do you want to send the file to? and given there is a bunch of .md, do you want them concatenated or how?

Comment: @EricWong I want to send them to a React front-end. I would like to send them without concatenation in the same request if possible. Otherwise with concatenation but how will the front-end know how to de-concatenate them?

Comment: I am not sure what it mean to "send them to a React front-end", a frontend cannot really "receive" data, do you mean to use say query string and your React will copy it into the HTML?

Comment: @EricWong yes. I think it should be ok like that

Comment: Well then we ran into a problem, with query string, the [length is limited to ~2k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers), so with this approach you cannot really "send" a compiled HTML >2k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems from the comment thread below the question that you want something that does the following:

- Converts all markdown files from a given directory to HTML
- Sends them all in a single request
- Is usable in a single-page app

Here's an approach that fulfils all of these requirements. The HTML of each post is inserted into a `template` element, the content of which can be cloned and manipulated within the SPA script.

#### server.js

```js
// with `.promises`, we can use `async/await`
const fs = require("fs").promises;

// ...

const getHtmlByFilename = async filename => {
  const md = await fs.readFile(
    path.join(__dirname, "posts", filename),
    "utf-8"
  );

  return converter.makeHtml(md);
};

app.get("/", async (request, response) => {
  const filenames = await fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, "posts"));

  // we can also use Promise.all
  // to map over the filenames in parallel
  const htmls = await Promise.all(
    filenames.map(async filename => {
      const html = await getHtmlByFilename(filename);

      return { filename, html };
    })
  );

  response.send(
    htmlBoilerplate(
      htmls
        .map(
          ({ filename, html }) =>
            `<template id="${filename}">${html}</template>`
        )
        .join("\n"),
      "<h1>SPA</h1>",
      '<script src="/public/spa.js"></script>'
    )
  );
});
```

#### public/spa.js

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("template")].forEach(template => {
  const clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);

  const filename = template.id;

  const details = document.createElement("details");
  const summary = document.createElement("summary");

  summary.textContent = filename;

  details.appendChild(summary);
  details.appendChild(clone);

  document.querySelector(".markdown-body").appendChild(details);
});
```

#### glitch.me demo

[Source](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/showdown-on-the-fly) | [Live](https://showdown-on-the-fly.glitch.me)

#### Limitations

- The conversion is done on-the-fly. If you have heavy traffic, you'll want to implement some caching, or perhaps simply save the HTML versions separately, and trigger updates to them whenever the corresponding Markdown is edited.
- The current code is probably not XSS safe — this assumes that either the content/filenames of posts are trusted, or that you carry out proper sanitation where required.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const {readdir, readFile} = require('fs');
const showdown  = require('showdown');
const axios = require('axios');

let fileHtmlList = [];

const converter = new showdown.Converter();

readdir(`${__dirname}/posts`, 'utf8', (fsDirError, fileNameList) => {
    if(!fsDirError) {
        fileNameList.forEach((fileName) => {
            readFile(`${__dirname}/posts/${fileName}`, 'utf8', (fsReadError, fileContent) => {
                if(!fsReadError) {
                    fileHtmlList.push({
                        fileName: `${__dirname}/posts/${fileName}`,
                        htmlContent: converter.makeHtml(fileContent)
                    }); 
                } else {
                    return console.error(fsReadError);
                }  
            });    
        });
    } else {
        return console.error(fsDirError);
    }
});

/* I'm guessing this part from your description, if the content needs to be rendered then the code needs change */

let sendFrontEnd = async (data) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`urlToSend`, data);
        console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};

fileHtmlList.forEach((item) => {
    sendFrontEnd(item.htmlContent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the sync variants of readdir and readFile

```
const basePath = __dirname + '/posts/';
const htmls = [];

fs.readdirSync(basePath).forEach(file => {
  const text = fs.readFileSync(basePath + file, 'utf8');
  htmls.push({
    file,
    html: converter.makeHtml(text)
  });
});

// upload htmls with axios/fetch/ ....
```

Comment: Why? This will bottleneck.

Comment: I thought he wants to send all the file with one post request which means he doesn't have that many files ... maybe I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

Try this js lib

```
<!-- Lightweight client-side loader that feature-detects and load polyfills only when necessary -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2/webcomponents-loader.min.js"></script>
<!-- Load the element definition -->
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/zerodevx/zero-md@1/src/zero-md.min.js"></script>
```

```
    <div class="markdown-body">
        <zero-md src="README.md"> </zero-md>
    </div>
```

I strongly recommend using zero markdown in html file  because

- Automatic update from your readme.md file.
- if you using convert readme to html, you must convert manually every time you update readme file (or code more).

Full html in my source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>API Get link Zing Mp3</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
      .markdown-body {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        min-width: 200px;
        max-width: 980px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 45px;
      }
    
      @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .markdown-body {
          padding: 15px;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Lightweight client-side loader that feature-detects and load polyfills only when necessary -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2/webcomponents-loader.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load the element definition -->
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/zerodevx/zero-md@1/src/zero-md.min.js"></script>

<!-- Simply set the `src` attribute to your MD file and win -->

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="markdown-body">
      <zero-md src="README.md">
      </zero-md>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

if you using nodejs, you can add a router to your readme.md file

```
app.get('/README.md', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "README.md"));
})
```