# RegExp: Inserting number of digits before any number

Tags: javascript, regex, sorting

I want to sort an array of strings that contain names and numbers. But I want to improve the alphanumerical sort order to get an order like

```
John 8 test
John 9 test
John 10 test
```

instead of having "John 10 test" at the top because "1" < "8" < "9". My idea is to insert the number of digits of a number bevore any number so internally the array to be sorted becomes:

```
John 18 test
John 19 test
John 210 test
```

which now is an alphanumeric correctly sorted array.

Any ideas how to insert the number of digits bevore the numer in an easy way? RegExp would be perfect. I am doing all this in nodejs/JavaScript.

Thanks in advance!

heinob

Comment: What if it had more than 9 digits or leading zeros? I think what you really need here is [natural sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2802341/7586).

Comment: This actually could be a problem but does not happen in my case, because the numbers are physical measurement values, which have no leading zeros and don't tend to have more than 9 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the (one) answer myself:

```
var a = "John 352 Name 1 test 23 better";
a.replace( /\d+/g, function( match, number) {
    return match.length + match;
});
```

Does what I want :-)

Comment: Thanks for your commitment. You definitly get the quickest-answer-price.