# jQuery - Sort array in ascending order

Tags: jquery

I need to sort the `nrArray` array:

```
var nrArray = nrArray.sort();
```

What the above does is this:

["1", "17", "206", "22", "3", "6"]

I need this:

["1", "3", "6", "17", "22", "206"]

Comment: to use sort() ... and that's what I did.

Comment: jQuery doesn't provide any functionality to sort collections.

Comment: looks like you are sorting alphabetically, and your array items are strings, not integers. Convert them to numbers then sort.

Comment: @Brino: That alone does not help because JavaScript's default `.sort` behavior is weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass in a comparison callback and use `parseInt` like

```js
var arr = ["1", "17", "206", "22", "3", "6"];

arr.sort(function(a, b){
  return parseInt(a)- parseInt(b);
});

console.log(arr);
```

**Update**

You actually dont need `parseInt` as `a/b` will be auto-converted to numbers. This is because you are subtracting and javascript performs the necessary type conversion. However, the same cannot be said for `a + b` as this is string concatenation.

Answer (score 5):

It is because by default the [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method will do a string based comparison

> compareFunction
>  Optional. Specifies a function that defines the
>   sort order. If omitted, the array is sorted according to each
>   character's Unicode code point value, according to the string
>   conversion of each element.

```js
var nrArray = ["22", "17", "8", "206", "1", "3", "6"];

nrArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});

console.log(nrArray)
```

Comment: `sort`, by default, always compares the the string representation of the values, no matter the actual data type.

Comment: @FelixKling, interestingly, Aruns answer works without `parseInt`. I assume it is because `a/b` are auto converted to perform the substraction. Is this behaviour safe across browsers?

Comment: @AmmarCSE: Yes. Subtraction is only defined on numbers, hence the operands will be converted to numbers.

Comment: @FelixKling, I see. It works for other operands as well.(I just tried `'1'*'3'` in the console). Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @AmmarCSE: Yep. JavaScript will always perform type conversion if necessary. It's pretty straightforward for operands that only support a single data type. `+` is trickier, it's defined for both strings and numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Applied from SO: [Sort Array Elements (string with numbers), natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478954/sort-array-elements-string-with-numbers-natural-sort)

You need a natural sort. A good generic natural sort providing the comparison to sort that will also work in case the strings also contain letters:

```
function naturalCompare(a, b) {
    var ax = [], bx = [];

    a.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function(_, $1, $2) { ax.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""]) });
    b.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function(_, $1, $2) { bx.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""]) });

    while(ax.length && bx.length) {
        var an = ax.shift();
        var bn = bx.shift();
        var nn = (an[0] - bn[0]) || an[1].localeCompare(bn[1]);
        if(nn) return nn;
    }

    return ax.length - bx.length;
}

var nrArray = nrArray.sort(naturalCompare);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes because your create array of strings not number.
 [1, 17, 206, 22, 3, 6] should work fine. moreover no need to write

var nrArray = nrArray.sort();

nrArray.sort(); changes the original array itself

Comment: a) It doesn't work with numbers either. b) You make it sound like assigning the return value of `.sort` would not change the original array. Is that what you mean? Because that is wrong as well.

Comment: Oops... my bad.....
 var nrArray = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
nrArray.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
should work.. sorry i didn't check before writing