# Nodejs filesystem array sort numeric

Tags: javascript, node.js

MY nodejs app reading some image files. But its sorting it alphabetically.

On the left side what Nodejs got and on the right side what should it looks like.

[image]
[image]

And my Nodejs code is:

```
var files = fs.readdirSync('./public/manga/' + req.params.name).map(function(item){
    var subfolders = fs.readdirSync('./public/manga/' + req.params.name + '/' + item);
    return {
        chapter: item,
        paths: subfolders.map(function (i) {
            return "manga/" + req.params.name + "/" + item + "/" + i;
        })
    }
})
res.json(files);
});
```

What I try and and didnt work.

```
var myarray=[25, 8, 7, 41]
myarray.sort(function(a,b){ //Array now becomes [7, 8, 25, 41]
return a - b
})
```

Comment: What's problem?

Comment: The filenames are strings, and are sorted alphanumerically. If you named the files 00, 01, 02, 03, etc it would sort as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) order.  There are **lots** of examples out there.

There's a good npm module for it https://github.com/Bill4Time/javascript-natural-sort.

You can also implement a quick function and there are lots of good examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15479354/2337565
- http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html
- https://github.com/litejs/natural-compare-lite

Comment: Thanks. That topic in this site solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in here will be in file names that has letter in it. But from your example since node already sorted 00Letter in correct order, I have simple solution like this

```
var a = ["10.jpg", "00a.jpg", "5.jpg", "00c.jpg", "3.jpg", "00b.jpg"];

var b = a.sort(function(a,b) {
  return parseInt(a) > parseInt(b);
});

console.log(b);
//output 
["00a.jpg", "00c.jpg", "00b.jpg", "3.jpg", "5.jpg", "10.jpg"]
```

**UPDATE**
As @Ding mentioned. Better to create custom function that captures everything and not hoping on node sort too.

Hope this helps.