# How to sort array based on the numbers in string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, sorting

Given this array = `[ "3ab1", "2a0", "1abc2" ]`

How do I sort it to `[ "1abc2", "3ab1", "2a0" ]` (descending order of the last number)

and return `[ 1,3,2 ]`. (the first numbers of each term)

When the last number and the next last number is not consecutive, the value returned should be 0.

`[ "2x2", "3x0", "2x1" ] ==> [ 2, 2, 3 ]`

`[ "22x0", "3x9", "2x1" ] ==> [ 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 22 ]`

`[ "2x4", "3x0" ] ==> [ 2, 0, 0, 3 ]`

`[ "axn", "bx(n-2)" ] ==> [ "axn", "0x(n-1)", bx(n-2) ] ==> [ a, 0, b ]`

I was thinking of converting to the array to string, replacing the number and letters in front and then sorting the array. But I do not know how put the part that was replaced back to its original number. This is my attempt on returning the final array once it is sorted.

```js
var ary = [ "1abc2", "3ab1", "2a0" ];

console.log(((ary.toString()).match(/\d+(?!,)/g)).slice(0, -1));
```

I saw these questions on sorting arrays based on numbers but they do not seem to work for me.

[How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

[Sort Array Elements (string with numbers), natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478954/sort-array-elements-string-with-numbers-natural-sort)

Comment: What are your sorting rules, I don't recognize a pattern?

Comment: sort it based on the number behind @myfunkyside then return the number in front

Comment: Is neither of those numbers ever longer than one digit (e.g. "4ab12" or "23a0")?

Comment: What's the logic? (explain in english)!

Comment: `[ "1x(n)", "1x(n-2)" ] ==> [ 1(of n), 0(of n-1)(since there is no (n-1 term it is taken to be 0)), 1(of n-2) ]` @ibrahimmahrir . Given the term ax(n) , if the following value of `n` in the next term is not (n-1), the value returned for (n-1) should be 0.

Comment: do i make sense @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: I've updated my answer if you're still interessted!

Comment: thanks so much @ibrahimmahrir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression to get the numbers when using `sort` and `reduce` to get the result:

```js
var array = [ "22x0", "3x9", "2x1" ];

var reS = /^\d+/,                          // regexp for getting all digits at the start of the string
    reE = /\d+$/;                          // regexp for getting all digits at the end of the string
var result = array.sort(function(a, b) {   // First: sort the array
    a = reE.exec(a);                       // get the last number from the string a
    b = reE.exec(b);                       // get the last number from the string b
    return b - a;                          // sort in a descending order
}).reduce(function(res, str, i) {          // Then: accumulate the result array 
    var gap = reE.exec(array[i - 1]) - reE.exec(str); // calculate the gap between this string str and the last string array[i - 1] (gap = N_of_last_string - N_of_this_string)
    if(gap > 0)                            // if there is a gap
        while(--gap) res.push(0);          // then fill it with 0s
    res.push(+reS.exec(str));              // push this string number
    return res;
}, []);

console.log("Sorted array:", array);       // array is now sorted
console.log("Result:", result);            // result contain the numbers
```

In recent ECMAScript versions you can do it shortly using arrow functions like this:

```js
let array = [ "22x0", "3x9", "2x1" ];

let reS = /^\d+/,                       
    reE = /\d+$/;                      
let result = array.sort((a, b) => reE.exec(b) - reE.exec(a))
                  .reduce((res, str, i) => { 
                      let gap = reE.exec(array[i - 1]) - reE.exec(str);
                      if(gap > 0)
                          while(--gap) res.push(0);
                      res.push(+reS.exec(str));
                      return res;
                  }, []);

console.log("Sorted array:", array); 
console.log("Result:", result);
```

Comment: what should i change if the first number can be negative as well?

Comment: @kaien Just the first number?

Comment: Change to `var reS = /^-?\d+/`!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit odd, but you can achieve this using `map` and `parseInt`:

```js
var arr = [ "1abc2", "3ab1", "2a0" ];

var res = arr.map(function (i) {
  return parseInt(i);
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of sort and map should do the trick.

```js
  const ary = [ "1abc2", "3ab1", "2a0" ];
  const newarray = ary
      .sort((a, b) => {
        return a[a.length - 1] < b[b.length - 1];
      })
      .map((a) =>  {
        return parseInt(a[0]);
      });
  console.log(newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The script below first sorts the array descending, based on the end-numbers,
and then returns only the start-numbers of the sorted array.

(I changed your numbers in the array to show that they can be longer than one digit.)

```js
var array = ["31ab12", "20a40", "11abc27"];

array.sort(function(a,b) {
  function getEndNum(str) {for (var i=str.length-1; i>=0; --i) {if (isNaN(str.charAt(i))) {return str.substring(i+1);}}} //this function returns the end-number of the supplied string
  return getEndNum(b) - getEndNum(a); //sort array descendingly, based on the end-numbers
});

console.log(array.map(function(a){return parseInt(a);})); //create a new array with only the start-numbers
```

*jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nu8vf837/*