# Getting coefficients of algebraic term

Tags: javascript, regex, math

Given a input of an algebraic term, I am trying to get the coefficients of the variables. The only operators in the input is `+ -` and only one variable.

**Examples:**

```
2x^2+3x+4 => [ 2, 3, 4 ]

3-x => [ -1, 3 ]

x^2+x => [ 1, 1, 0 ]

x+x^3 => [ 1, 0, 1, 0 ]
```

Invalid Input:

```
2x^2+2x^2
```

This is my first attempt at it:

```js
var str = " 2x^4-1+9x^3-100x^2";

    function getCoeff(term) {

        var nterm = (term.replace(/[^0-9|-]x(?!\^)/g,"1x")).replace(/[^0-9|\+]x(?!\^)/g,"-1x"); // ==> Replace ‘-/x’ with ‘-/1x’

        for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) { // ==> Loop true the regexs to replace all ‘x^n’ to ‘1x^n’

            var re = new RegExp('[^0-9|\-]x\\^' + i); // ==> Regex for x^n
            var re2 = new RegExp('[^0-9|]x\\^' + i); // ==> Regex for -x^n

            nterm = (nterm.replace(re,"1x^" + i)).replace(re2,"-1x^" + i); }

        for ( var m = 10; m > 1; m--  ) { // ==> Get the coefficients of ax^n in descending order
            var re3 = new RegExp('\\W?\\d+(?=x\\^' + m + ')' ); 
            if ( nterm.match(re3) === null ) {
                var result = "";
            } else {
                result += ((nterm.match(re3)+', ').toString()).replace(/\+/g,""); }}

        if ( nterm.match(/\W?\d+(?=x(?!\^))/g) === null ) { // Regex for coefficient x
            var result2 = "";
        } else {
            result2 = ((nterm.match(/\W?\d+(?=x(?!\^))/g)).toString()).replace(/\+/g,"") + ',';  }

        if ( nterm.match(/[^\^]\d+(?!\d|x)/g) === null ) { // Regex for constant
            var result3 = "";
        } else {
            result3 = ((nterm.match(/[^\^]\d+(?!\d|x)/g)).toString()).replace(/\+/g,""); }

        console.log(('[' + ' ' + result + result2 + ' ' + result3 + ']' ).replace(/\s/g,"")); }

    getCoeff(str)
```

Problems:

- Does not work when there is a missing `x term`.

Eg: `x^4 + x + 1 ==> Expected: [1, 0, 0, 1, 1] ==> Actual: [ 1, 1 ]`

- `x` should return `[ 1,0 ]` , but it returns `[ 1, ]`

This is my second attempt at it.

```js
var str = "-999x^2+x^3+x+3";
function getCoeff(string) {
if ( string.charAt(0) === 'x' ) { // If the first term is x, because of my regex it needs a space to match it
    string = ' ' + string;
}

for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) { // ==> Loop true the regexs to replace all ‘x^n’ to ‘1x^n’

    var re = new RegExp('[^0-9|\-]x\\^' + i);
    var re2 = new RegExp('[^0-9|]x\\^' + i);
    string = (string.replace(re,"+1x^" + i)).replace(re2," -1x^" + i); } 

var final = string.replace(/-/g,'+-'); // ==> Spilt(‘x’) later so to retain the -ve sign

final = (final.replace(/[^0-9|-]x(?!\^)/g,"+1x")).replace(/[^0-9|+]x(?!\^)/g,"-1x");  // ==> Replace ‘-/x’ with ‘-/1x’

final = final.replace(/[^\^](\d+(?!\d|x))/g,'+$1x^0'); // ==> Replace ‘c’ with ‘cx^0’
final = final.replace(/x(?!\^)/g, "x^1"); // ==> Replace ‘x’ with ‘x^1’
final = final.split('+'); // ==> Right now array looks something like this [ ax^(n), bx^(n-1), … yx^1,  zx^0]
final = final.filter(function(entry) { return entry.trim() !== ''; }); // Sorts array by the number behind in descending order

var reS = /^-?\d+/,
    reE = /\d+$/;
var result = final.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = reE.exec(a);
    b = reE.exec(b);
    return b - a;
}).reduce(function(res, str, i) {
    var gap = reE.exec(final[i - 1]) - reE.exec(str);
    if(gap > 0)
        while(--gap) res.push(0);
    res.push(+reS.exec(str));
    return res;
}, []); // Return the coefficients
console.log("Result:", result); 
}

getCoeff(str);
```

Questions:

1. Is there a way to do it without using regular expressions mostly?
2. How do I fix this problem? When no constant term is

   `getCoeff(“x^3”) ==> [ 1 ] , when it should give [ 1, 0, 0 ]`
3. How can I make my code more efficient?
4. How to match `x^n` terms but not `-x^n` terms using regex? This is my current one: `[^0-9|\-]x\\^' + i`, but it needs a space in front of it.

Reference:

[How to sort array based on the numbers in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432603/how-to-sort-array-based-on-the-numbers-in-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function getCoef(str) {
  str = str.replace(/\s+/g, "");                   // remove spaces (optional)
  
  var parts = str.match(/[+\-]?[^+\-]+/g);         // get the parts: see explanation bellow

  // accumulate the results
  return parts.reduce(function(res, part) {        // for each part in parts
    var coef = parseFloat(part) || +(part[0] + "1") || 1;// the coeficient is the number at the begining of each part (34x => 34), if there is no number it is assumed to be +/-1 depending on the sign (+x^2 => +1)
    var x = part.indexOf('x');                     // the index of "x" in this part (could be -1 if there isn't)
    // calculating the power of this part
    var power = x === -1 ?                         // if the index of "x" is -1 (there is no "x")
                  0:                               // then the power is 0 (Ex: -2)
                  part[x + 1] === "^" ?            // otherwise (if there is an "x"), then check if the char right after "x" is "^", if so...
                    +part.slice(x + 2) :           // then the power is the number right after it (Ex: 55x^30)
                    1;                             // otherwise it's 1 (Ex: 55x)
    res[power] = (res[power] || 0) + coef;         // if we have already encountered this power then add this coeficient to that, if not then just store it 
    return res;
  }, {});
}

/** TESTS **/
[
  "-999x^2 + x^3 + x + 3", "5x + 3 - 10x", "55x^3 + 1", "55.12x^4 + 20x^4 - 120x^4"
].forEach(function(test) {
  console.log(test, "=>", getCoef(test));
});
```

**The output:**

The result of the function `getCoef` will be an object in this format:

```
{
    "power": "coeficient",
    "other power": "other coeficient",
    ...
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. `str = str.replace(/\s+/g, "");`:

Removing spaces (obvious).

2. `var parts = str.match(/[+\-]?[^+\-]+/g);`:

Split the string into parts. The string `"-5x^2-3+10x"` will return `["-5x^2", "-3", "+10x"]`. The regex will look for:

```
[+\-]?  : a "+" or "-" sign (if any)
[^+\-]+ : anything that isn't a "+" nor "-" (get everything up until the new + or - or the end is reached)
g       : to get all parts
```

3. `var coef = parseFloat(part) || +(part[0] + "1") || 1;`:

Get the coeficient of this part using:

```
parseFloat     : for parts that have a number before "x" like: "+55x", "-34.22x^11", "5x", ...
+(part[0] + 1) : for parts that have only a sign like: "+x", "-x^2", ... (get the sign part[0] concatinate it with "1" and then cast the result into a number using binary +)
1              : for parts that doesn't have a number nor a sign like "x^3", "x", ...
```

just note that parts like `"0x^4"` will be assumed as having a coeficient of 1 using the above (but I don't see why one will need a null coeficient anyway)!

4. `var x = part.indexOf('x');`:

Get the index of the character `"x"` in the part to distinguish between parts that have it like `"3x"`, `"x^11"`, ... and parts that doesn't like `"+5"`, ...

5. `var power = ...`:

If there isn't an `"x"` in the part (`x === -1`) then the power of this part is `0`.

Otherwise (an `"x"` is present), then we check if the character right after `"x"` (`part[x + 1]`) is `"^"`, if it is then the power is whaterver number that comes after it (cut that bit of the string `part.slice(x + 2)` and cast it to number using unary `+`), if there isn't a `"^"` after `"x"`, then the power is `1`.

6. `res[power] = (res[power] || 0) + coef;`:

Add the coeficient `coef` that has just been calculated to the already accumulated coeficient of this power (if nothing is accumulated then use `0`).

This line could be simplified like this:

```
if(res[power])         // if we already encountered this power in other parts before
  res[power] += coef;  // then add this coeficient to the sum of those previous coeficients
else                   // otherwise
  res[power] = coef;   // start a new sum initialized with this coeficient
```

this makes it possible to include the same power more than one time in the same string like: `"5x + 10x + 1 + x"`, ...

**Transform the resultant object into the desired array:**

So that:

```
{
    "3": 7,
    "0": 19
}
```

will be:

```
[7, 0, 0, 19]
```

```js
var ret = { "3": 7, "0": 19 }; // the returned object

var powers = Object.keys(ret); // get all the powers (in this case [3, 0])

var max = Math.max.apply(null, powers); // get the max power from powers array (in this case 3)

var result = [];
for(var i = max; i >= 0; i--)  // from the max power to 0
  result.push(ret[i] || 0);    // if that power has a coeficient then push it, otherwise push 0
  
console.log(result);
```