# Array sorting according to time in string

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, datetime, object

I have an array of objects. I want to sort the array according to the object key. For example below -

```
{
   "id": 3511,
   "time": "03:30",
   "hour": 3,
   "utc_date_time": "2020-07-07T02:07:54.000Z",
   "members": 0
},
{
   "id": 3514,
   "time": "04:30",
   "hour": 4,
   "utc_date_time": "2020-07-07T02:07:54.000Z",
   "members": 0
},
{
   "id": 3513,
   "time": "04:00",
   "hour": 4,
   "utc_date_time": "2020-07-07T02:07:54.000Z",
   "members": 0
},
```

I want to sort it according to time like this-

```
{
   "id": 3511,
   "time": "03:30",
   "hour": 3,
   "utc_date_time": "2020-07-07T02:07:54.000Z",
   "members": 0
},
{
   "id": 3513,
   "time": "04:00",
   "hour": 4,
   "utc_date_time": "2020-07-07T02:07:54.000Z",
   "members": 0
},
{
   "id": 3514,
   "time": "04:30",
   "hour": 4,
   "utc_date_time": "2020-07-07T02:07:54.000Z",
   "members": 0
},
```

I have used this function to sort but it is not giving the expected output I have also used the time key, still the same.

```js
timeSlots.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.time- b.time;
});
```

But not getting an expected output.

Comment: how can i convert time key? i need it to be according to time key

Comment: Do you want to sort based on time or hour? Your question is regarding time but your sort in regarding hour

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort Array Elements (string with numbers), natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478954/sort-array-elements-string-with-numbers-natural-sort)

Comment: @Codenewbie Why `parseFloat()`? `hour` is already a number o.O

Comment: actually even if its a string javascript will coerce it

Comment: @Ifaruki yeah u r ryt

Comment: @Ifaruki—not in a [*sort*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort), strings are sorted lexically. Try `['3','06'].sort()`.

Comment: @RobG yea. but i meant sorting like this is coerced `["3", "5", "4", "9" , "1"].sort((a,b) => a - b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `.time` values are in `HH:MM` format, you can sort them as strings:

```js
let array = [{
    "id": 3511,
    "time": "03:30",
    "hour": 3,
    "utc_date_time": "2020-07-07T02:07:54.000Z",
    "members": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 3514,
    "time": "04:30",
    "hour": 4,
    "utc_date_time": "2020-07-07T02:07:54.000Z",
    "members": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 3513,
    "time": "04:00",
    "hour": 4,
    "utc_date_time": "2020-07-07T02:07:54.000Z",
    "members": 0
  }
];

array.sort((a, b) => a.time.localeCompare(b.time));
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lodash's "`sortBy`" is perfect for this.

```
_.sortBy(timeSlots, 'time');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can pass a *compare function* to `sort` method saying how you want to sort the array elements. Thus, it provides a way to sort objects too.

To sort in ascending order:

```
const sortedArrayOfObjects = array.sort((item1, item2) => {
    if(item1.id < item2.id) return -1
    else if(item1.id > item2.id) return 1
    else return 0;
});
```

- If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns less than 0, sort `a` to an index lower than `b` (i.e. `a` comes first).
- If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave `a` and `b` unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements.
- If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns greater than 0, sort `b` to an index lower than `a` (i.e. `b` comes first).

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr =    [{
        "id": 3511,
        "time": "03:30",
        "hour": 3,
        "utc_date_time": "2020-07-07T02:07:54.000Z",
        "members": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3514,
        "time": "04:30",
        "hour": 4,
        "utc_date_time": "2020-07-07T02:07:54.000Z",
        "members": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3513,
        "time": "04:00",
        "hour": 4,
        "utc_date_time": "2020-07-07T02:07:54.000Z",
        "members": 0
    }]
    

sortedArr = arr.sort(function(a, b){
                if (a['time'] < b['time']) return -1;
                if (a['time'] > b['time']) return 1;
                return 0
           })

console.log(`sorted: `, sortedArr);
```