# Why TypeScript Array sort is not sorting correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting

I have an array with 54 elements. I want to sort it by it's transactionAmount. Here are the code and console.log output:-

```
sortData(sort: Sort) {
const data = this.dataSource.filteredData;
console.log('Before sort');
this.logAll(this.dataSource.filteredData as TransactionSearch[]);
(data as TransactionSearch[]).sort((left, right) => {
// (this.dataSource.filteredData as TransactionSearch[]).sort((left, right) => {
  const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
  switch (sort.active) {
    case 'currency':
      return this.compareTransactionRow(left.currency, right.currency, isAsc);
    case 'processingState':
      return this.compareTransactionRow(left.processingState, right.processingState, isAsc);
    case 'transactionAmount':
      return this.compareTransactionRow(left.transactionAmount, right.transactionAmount, isAsc);
    case 'messageFunction':
      return this.compareTransactionRow(left.messageFunction, right.messageFunction, isAsc);
    case 'transactionDate':
      return this.compareTransactionRow(left.transactionDate, right.transactionDate, isAsc);
    default: return 0;
  }
});
this.dataSource.filteredData = data;
console.log('After sort');
this.logAll(this.dataSource.filteredData as TransactionSearch[]);
 }

 compareTransactionRow(left: string | Date, right: string | Date, isAsc: boolean) {
let result = 0;
if ( left < right ) {
  result = -1;
} else if ( left > right) {
  result = 1;
}
result = result * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
return result;
}

 logAll(data: TransactionSearch[]) {
let i = 0;
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
data.forEach( element => {
    console.log('Element: ' + i.toString());
    // console.log(element);
    console.log('element.transactionAmount: ' + element.transactionAmount);
    i++;
  }
);
}
```

it is a huge array of 54 elements. So before sort console.log():

```
 Element: 0
 element.transactionAmount: 30.00
 Element: 1
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 2
 element.transactionAmount: 1.00
 Element: 3
 element.transactionAmount: 3.00
 Element: 4
 element.transactionAmount: 3.00
 Element: 5
 element.transactionAmount: 1.00
 Element: 6
 element.transactionAmount: 2.00
 Element: 7
 element.transactionAmount: 2.00
 Element: 8
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 9
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 10
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 11
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 12
 element.transactionAmount: 12.00
 Element: 13
 element.transactionAmount: 12.00
 Element: 14
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 15
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 16
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 17
 element.transactionAmount: 1.00
 Element: 18
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 19
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 20
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 21
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 22
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 23
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 24
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 25
 element.transactionAmount: 1.00
 Element: 26
 element.transactionAmount: 2.00
 Element: 27
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 28
 element.transactionAmount: 2.00
 Element: 29
 element.transactionAmount: 2.00
 Element: 30
 element.transactionAmount: 2.00
 Element: 31
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 32
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 33
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 34
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 35
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 36
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 37
 element.transactionAmount: 50.00
 Element: 38
 element.transactionAmount: 50.00
 Element: 39
 element.transactionAmount: 50.00
 Element: 40
 element.transactionAmount: 50.00
 Element: 41
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 42
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 43
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 44
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 45
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 46
 element.transactionAmount: 30.00
 Element: 47
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 48
 element.transactionAmount: 1.00
 Element: 49
 element.transactionAmount: 1.00
 Element: 50
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 51
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 52
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 53
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
```

After sorting it is as follows:-

```
 Element: 0
 element.transactionAmount: 1.00
 Element: 1
 element.transactionAmount: 1.00
 Element: 2
 element.transactionAmount: 1.00
 Element: 3
 element.transactionAmount: 1.00
 Element: 4
 element.transactionAmount: 1.00
 Element: 5
 element.transactionAmount: 1.00
 Element: 6
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 7
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 8
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 9
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 10
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 11
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 12
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 13
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 14
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 15
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 16
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 17
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 18
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 19
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 20
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 21
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 22
 element.transactionAmount: 10.00
 Element: 23
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 24
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 25
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 26
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 27
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 28
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 29
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 30
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 31
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 32
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 33
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 34
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 35
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 36
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 37
 element.transactionAmount: 100.00
 Element: 38
 element.transactionAmount: 12.00
 Element: 39
 element.transactionAmount: 12.00
 Element: 40
 element.transactionAmount: 2.00
 Element: 41
 element.transactionAmount: 2.00
 Element: 42
 element.transactionAmount: 2.00
 Element: 43
 element.transactionAmount: 2.00
 Element: 44
 element.transactionAmount: 2.00
 Element: 45
 element.transactionAmount: 2.00
 Element: 46
 element.transactionAmount: 3.00
 Element: 47
 element.transactionAmount: 3.00
 Element: 48
 element.transactionAmount: 30.00
 Element: 49
 element.transactionAmount: 30.00
 Element: 50
 element.transactionAmount: 50.00
 Element: 51
 element.transactionAmount: 50.00
 Element: 52
 element.transactionAmount: 50.00
 Element: 53
 element.transactionAmount: 50.00
```

As you can see it is correctly sorted. What is wrong with this sorting.

Comment: [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

Comment: well, it is not just an array of integers. I have an interface with the possibility to sort by all the elements. This example I only showed sort by transactionAmount. But users can sort by date or other elements in the interface. But the basic sorting should be simple and working. But it doesn't work.

Comment: You can check type `left` and `right` params in `compareTransactionRow` and depending on the type perform different types of sorts

Comment: because they are `string` and not `numbers`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort Array Elements (string with numbers), natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478954/sort-array-elements-string-with-numbers-natural-sort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you compare the values as `string` and not as `numbers`, you can parse the values:

```
 compareTransactionRow(left: string | Date, right: string | Date, isAsc: boolean) {
   let result = 0;
   if (typeof left === "string" && typeof right === "string") {
     left = parseFloat(left);
     right = parseFloat(right);
   } 
   if ( left < right ) {
     result = -1;
   } else if ( left > right) {
     result = 1;
   }
   result = result * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
   return result;
  }
```

Comment: There are many duplicates of sorting numeric strings. No need to answer them all.