# Algorithm to sort an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, natural-sort

I am having difficulty figuring out a solution.

I have an array similar to this.

```
// Original array 
const orig_array = ["2", "10", "01A", "1A", "02B", "1","03B"]; 

// The sorted array needs to be like this. 
sorted_array = ["1", "1A", "01A", "2", "02B", "03B", "10"];
```

I have tried writing a custom sort function like this but I am unable to find a solution. I appreciate any help.

```
 const orig_array = ["2", "10", "01A", "1A", "02B", "1","03B"];

 const sorted_array = orig_array.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a - b) {
   return a - b;
  }
 if (a.localeCompare(b) === -1) {
  return a.length - b.length;
 } else {
 return 1;
}
});
console.log(sorted_array);
```

Comment: What is your criteria for sorting?

Comment: You should probably clarify that you're looking for a natural and not lexicographic sort

Comment: Why is `10 > 1A`? That's unusual.

Comment: @jabaa It's a natural sort, and `10 > 1`

Comment: @Unmitigated Why do you think this is not a duplicate of the [canonical "natural sort" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478954/sort-array-elements-string-with-numbers-natural-sort)? The accepted answer there does produce the exact result the OP wants. For anything else, this question should be closed as unclear.

Comment: @Bergi The accepted answer may place `01A` before `1A`.

Comment: @Unmitigated Ah, right, they are considered equal by a normal natural sort. Change `return ax.length - bx.length;` to `return ax.length - bx.length || a.length - b.length;` for placing the one with leading zeroes after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first apply `parseInt` to both strings to get the first numeric parts and subtract them. If the numeric parts are equal, then subtract the lengths.

```js
const orig_array = ["2", "10", "01A", "1A", "02B", "1","03B"]; 
console.log(orig_array.sort((a,b)=>parseInt(a)-parseInt(b)||a.length-b.length));
```

Comment: I think the OP still wants to sort lexically, not by length, if the numeric prefixes match.

Comment: Say in `01B` and `01A`, when the numeric parts are equal, don't you want to put the one with `A` before the one with `B`? Also, if there are no numeric parts, don't you compare the letters?

Comment: @Bergi The expected result does not match with that. The code in the question is also subtracting the lengths, so it seems like it is a criteria.

Comment: @Unmitigated `""` comes before `"A"` comes before `"B"` in a lexical sort, which is consistent with the expected `sorted_array`? OP also uses `a.localeCompare(b)` in his code (admittedly in a weird way).

Comment: @Bergi Perhaps this one then: `orig_array.sort((a,b)=>parseInt(a)-parseInt(b)||a.replace(/^\d+/, '').localeCompare(b.replace(/^\d+/,''))||a.length-b.length)`

Comment: @Unmitigated the above solution is working perfectly for the dataset that I have. Thanks a lot!