# How to sort a javascript array alphabetically with numbers at the end (after letters), and correctly sorting numerically?

Tags: javascript

The current output of my array is:

`"10 FOOT", "45 RPM", "9 VOLT", "910D0", "AGUA", "BEAST", "KEN 5", "NEMCO"`

What I want is:

`"AGUA", "BEAST", "KEN 5", "NEMCO", "9 VOLT", "10 FOOT", "45 RPM:, "910D0"`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: why would a number at the end have precedence over sorting alpha numerically? No wait, what has actually that number at the end have anything to do with the question?

Comment: does this post solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939726/javascript-array-sorting-only-first-letter-only-first-number

Comment: You need to explain more about your sorting criteria...

Comment: Let's clarify a bit, is this what you want? If an element starts with a letter, sort it alphabetically. If it starts with a number, sort it by the value of the number (not only the first digit), and finally, those starting with a number should go after the ones starting with a letter?

Comment: Please post compilable code. Those quotes throw an error.

Comment: sorry if I was unclear. I'll try and demonstrate with examples. 1) http://tf-ref.com/wp_martinez_1/ - this works perfectly in wordpress/php you can see the desired order here (scroll to the bottom to see how numbers are correctly ordered, and following on from letters). 2) in javascript/react however I am getting - https://martinez-gallery-build.netlify.app/ by default.

Comment: the above comment by 'blex' states in better words than I can muster, what I am effectively trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the string starts with a digit and sort the rest by groups.

```js
const array = ['10 FOOT', '45 RPM', '9 VOLT', '910D0', 'AGUA', 'BEAST', 'KEN 5', 'NEMCO'];

array.sort((a, b) => isFinite(a[0]) - isFinite(b[0])
    || a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' })
);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const order = ["10 FOOT", "45 RPM", "9 VOLT", "910D0", "AGUA", "BEAST", "KEN 5", "NEMCO"];

order.sort((a, b) => /^[0-9]/.test(a) - /^[0-9]/.test(b) || a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }));

console.log(order);
```

Sort elements starting with a number first, afterwards use localeCompare's numeric option (which ensures "10" > "2").

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = ["10 FOOT", "45 RPM", "9 VOLT", "910D0", "AGUA", "BEAST", "KEN 5", "NEMCO"];

const customCompare = (a, b) => 
  /^\d/.test(a) - /^\d/.test(b) || 
  a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true });

const sorted = arr.sort(customCompare);

console.log(...sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 new arrays, sort them and put them back together:

```
const arr = ["10 FOOT", "45 RPM", "9 VOLT", "910D0", "AGUA", "BEAST", "KEN 5", "NEMCO"];
const nums = arr.filter(a => parseInt(a))
const words = arr.filter(a => !parseInt(a))

nums.sort((a,b) => parseInt(a) -parseInt(b))
words.sort()

const finalArray = words.concat(nums)
```