# Alphanumeric sorting an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to resort a list of dynamically created SELECT OPTIONS in javascript.

I have no access to the source, otherwise I would change this from the server code.

This is the select:

```
<select class="text12 width_constrained" name="/web/personalisation/request/DesignConsultationRequestFormHandler.addressItem">
<option value="1|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">1 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="3|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">3 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="5|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">5 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="7|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">7 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="9|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">9 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="11|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">11 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="13|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">13 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="15|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">15 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="17|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">17 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="19|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">19 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="21|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">21 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="23|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">23 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="25|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">25 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="27|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">27 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="2|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">2 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="4|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">4 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="6|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">6 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="8|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">8 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="10|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">10 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="12|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">12 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="14|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">14 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="16|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">16 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="18|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">18 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="20|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">20 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="22|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">22 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="24|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">24 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="26|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">26 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
<option value="28|Marsh Gardens||Southampton, Hedge End|Hampshire|SO30 2XN|United Kingdom|false|false|false|false|false|false|false">28 Marsh Gardens, Southampton, Hedge End, SO30 2XN</option>
```

I am currently using the following, but it only sorts by the first character using the natural sort, which does not support alphanumeric...

```
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
var opts = jQuery('form[name=consultationForm] select option');

console.log("options");
console.log(opts);

var arr = opts.map(function(_, o) {
    return {
        t: jQuery(o).text(),
        v: o.value
    };
}).get();

console.log("options post sort");
//arr.sort();


arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
    return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
});

console.log(arr);

});
```

The obvious desired output is to have all the options ordered in numeric value, but also allowing for subsets e.g. 2a, 2b, 2c.

Can anyone help further?

Comment: consider using a split.

Comment: What do you mean by : "but also allowing for subsets e.g. 2a, 2b, 2c." ?

Comment: So where address are "1 Marsh Gardens", "2 Marsh Gardens"...you could have "1 Marsh Gardens", "2a Marsh Gardens", "2b Marsh Gardens"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is Natural Sort, i found this code sample here: [Javascript : natural sort of alphanumerical strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/natural-sort-of-text-and-numbers-javascript)  This will give proper sorting for values like 2a, 2b, 2c, as well as values without a street number.

```
function naturalSorter(as, bs){
    var a, b, a1, b1, i= 0, n, L,
    rx=/(\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?)|([^\d.]+)|(\.\D+)|(\.$)/g;
    if(as=== bs) return 0;
    a= as.toLowerCase().match(rx);
    b= bs.toLowerCase().match(rx);
    L= a.length;
    while(i<L){
        if(!b[i]) return 1;
        a1= a[i],
        b1= b[i++];
        if(a1!== b1){
            n= a1-b1;
            if(!isNaN(n)) return n;
            return a1>b1? 1:-1;
        }
    }
    return b[i]? -1:0;
}
```

Then

```
arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
    return naturalSorter(o1.t, o2.t);
});
```

I edited TJ's fiddle slightly to give an example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/464W2/3/)

Comment: This sorted it for me, although you have a spelling mistake in the function call in the arr.sort. Many thanks

Comment: Thanks for the catch, all fixed up.

Answer (score 1):

Your strings are probably converted to numbers because they start with a digit. You can try the following sort function:

```
arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
    return o1.t.localeCompare(o2.t);
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare for more information.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to implement this:

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'localeCompare'

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `t` key. Added it to the example.

Comment: This seems to randomly sort the output list

Comment: @Kimear - the `o2.t1` is a typo; it should be `o2.t`.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `localeSort` should do what you want if used properly.  If, for some reason, you need to implement your own sort comparison, try this:

```
arr.sort(function(o1, o2) { 
    return o1.t.split(/(\d+|\D+)/)[1] - o2.t.split(/(\d+|\D+)/)[1] 
} );
```

The `split` creates an array of alternating numeric and non-numeric strings (with empty strings between them that we can ignore for this purpose).  Element 0 of the array is empty, so element 1 is the first component - the house number, with no extraneous characters that will make the numeric converter treat it as `NaN`.  The subtraction forces the conversion from string to number, and you're good to go.

That idea generalizes to a full natural sort by examining as much of each string as necessary:

```
arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
           var a = o1.t.split(/(\d+|\D+)/).filter(function(s){return s!=""});
           var b = o2.t.split(/(\d+|\D+)/).filter(function(s){return s!=""});
           for (var cmp = 0, i = 0; 0 == cmp && i < a.length && i < b.length; i++) {
             var n1 = a[i] - 0, n2 = b[i] - 0;
             if (!isNaN(n1) && !isNaN(n2)) 
               cmp = n1 - n2;
             else if (a[i] < b[i]) 
               cmp = -1;
             else if (a[i] > b[i])
               cmp = 1;
           }
           return cmp;
         })
```

Comment: Close answer, but this doesn't react well to an address that has no house number and puts those randomly through the address output.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2UJHm/2/) to demonstrate the re-ordering. I stored the values of the `value` and `text` attribute in an array as well as the parsed street number. No the sorting is easier.
 One could argue that my code is a bit bloated and there probably is a more elegant way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var selectModel = []; // We use this to store all the option data

    $('select.text12 option').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        selectModel.push({
            value: $this.val(),
            text: $this.text(),
            index: parseInt($this.val().split('|')[0], 10) // Make sure it's a number
        });
    });

    selectModel.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.index - b.index;
    });

    var tempHtml = '';

    for (var i = 0, ii = selectModel.length; i < ii; i++) {
        tempHtml += '<option value="' + selectModel[i].value + '">' + selectModel[i].text + '</option>';
    }

    // Here the option html is recreated
    $('select.text12').html(tempHtml);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone wants a sorting algorithm that doesn't include a regex. I would assume it's faster, but haven't tested that.

```
function alphanum(a, b) {
  function chunkify(t) {
    var tz = [], x = 0, y = -1, n = 0, i, j;

    while (i = (j = t.charAt(x++)).charCodeAt(0)) {
      var m = (i == 46 || (i >=48 && i <= 57));
      if (m !== n) {
        tz[++y] = "";
        n = m;
      }
      tz[y] += j;
    }
    return tz;
  }

  var aa = chunkify(a);
  var bb = chunkify(b);

  for (x = 0; aa[x] && bb[x]; x++) {
    if (aa[x] !== bb[x]) {
      var c = Number(aa[x]), d = Number(bb[x]);
      if (c == aa[x] && d == bb[x]) {
        return c - d;
      } else return (aa[x] > bb[x]) ? 1 : -1;
    }
  }
  return aa.length - bb.length;
}
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/464W2/61/).

Answer (score 0):

I Modified the script to work with objects (natural sorting by object property)

### Code

```
function alphanumCase(a, b, prop) {
    function chunkify(t) {
        var tz = new Array();
        var x = 0, y = -1, n = 0, i, j;

        while (i = (j = t.charAt(x++)).charCodeAt(0)) {
            var m = (i == 46 || (i >=48 && i <= 57));
            if (m !== n) {
                tz[++y] = "";
                n = m;
            }
            tz[y] += j;
        }
        return tz;
    }

    var aa = chunkify(a[prop].toLowerCase());
    var bb = chunkify(b[prop].toLowerCase());

    for (x = 0; aa[x] && bb[x]; x++) {
        if (aa[x] !== bb[x]) {
            var c = Number(aa[x]), d = Number(bb[x]);
            if (c == aa[x] && d == bb[x]) {
                return c - d;
            } else return (aa[x] > bb[x]) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    return aa.length - bb.length;
}
```

---

### Usage

```
someArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    //sort naturally by the name property (a.name vs b.name)
    return alphanumCase(a, b, 'name');
});
```