# sorting in Alphanumeric in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have data in select field like this

```
72A(6) , 72(A)(6A) , 78(1) , 72AB(1) , 79 , 80QQB , 80RRB , 80TTA , 80U , 80CCC , 80CCD , 80CCE , 80CCF , 80CCG , 80D , 80DD , 80DDB , 80E , 80EE , 80G , 92C(4) , 80G(2)(c ) , 80G(5) , 80GG , 80C , 80GGA , 80GGB , 80GGC , 80-IA , 80-IA(4) , 80-IA(4)(ii) , 80-IA(4)(iii) , 80-IA(4)(iv) , 80-IA(4)(v) , 80-IA(5) , 80-IA(4)(i) , 80-IA(12) , 80-IAB , 80-IB , 80-IB(2) , 80-IB(3) , 80-IB(4) , 80-IB(5) , 80-IB(11) , 80-IB(7) , 80-IB(7A) , 80-IB(7B) , 80-IB(8A) , 80-IB(9) , 80-IB(10) , 80-IB(11A) , 80-IB(11B) , 80-IB(11C) , 80-IC , 80-ID , 80-ID(3) , 80-IE , 80JJA , 80LA , 80JJAA , 80P , 56(2)(vii) , 184(2) , 184 , 144 , 184(5) , 185 , 47(xiiib) , 32(1) , 35DDA(4A) , 43(1) , 43(6) , 47A(4) , 49(1) , 49(2AAA) , 72A(6A) , 115JAA , 167C , 36 , 37 , 40(b) , 40A(2) , 187(2) , 115JC , 115JD , 115JEE , 115JE , 115JF , 187 , 170 , 188 , 189 , 188A , 2(31) , 111A , 112 , 86 , 80P(2)(a)(iii) , 11 , 11(1)(d) , 12 , 11(1) , 11(2) , 11(5) , 11(3) , 11(3A) , 115BBC , 11(1A) , 2(24)(vi) , 11(4) , 11(4A) , 12A , 12AA , 2(15) , 13(8) , 13 , 13(3) , 13(2) , 164 , 161 , 143(3) , 115JB , 115JB(5) , 2(26) , 115-O(6) , 115-O(3) , 115-O(4) , 115P , 115Q , 10(34) , 2(22)(e) , 2(18) , 6(3) , 115T , 115R , 115TA , 115TA(2) , 115TB , 115TC , 115U , 115QA(3) , 115QA(4) , 115QA(5) , 115QB , 115QC , 115QA , 115R(3) , 115VS , 115VE , 115VX , 115V-I (1) , 115V-I (2) , 115V-I (5) , 115V-I (6) , 115V-I (7) , 115VA , 115V-I (8) , 115VT , 115VT(2) , 115VT(3) , 115VT(4) , 115VT(5) , 115VL , 115VK , 115VN , 115VY , 115VB , 115VC , 115VZ , 115VO , 115VZA , 115VZB , 115VZC , 115VD , 115VP , 115VQ(1) , 115VQ(2) , 194LB , 194LC , 194LD , 9(1) , 115A , 2(30) , 115AB , 115AC , 115AD , 115BBA , 115E , 115(C)(b) , 115(C)(f) , 115D , 115F , 115G , 115H , 115-I , 115A(1)(a) , 115JG , 163 , 139(1) , 145(3) , 145 , 144A , 144C , 144C(15) , 144BA , 144BA(2) , 144BA(6) , 144C(1) , 18B , 18BA , 30 , 31 , 32 , 33 , 35GA , 35A , 35B , 35C , 35D , 35E , 35EE , 35EEE , 35FG , 34A , 35H , 35HA , 3 , 2(ea)(ii) , 2(ea)(iii) , 2(ea)(iv) , 2(ea)(v) , 2(ea)(vi) , 4(1)(a) , 4 , 4(1) , 4(1)(6) , 5(i) , 5(ii) , 5(iii) , 45 , 5(iv) , 5(v) , 5(vi) , 2(q) , 5 , 44C , 44D , 2(c ) , 7 , 7(2) , 7(1) , 14(1) , 14(2) , 15A , 60 , 273A(2) , 174A , 175 , 64(1)(iv) , 80B , 2(23) , 234B(3) , 90(2A) , 6 , 6(6)(a) , 194E , 234D , 6(6)(b) , 115BB , 5(2) , 56(2)(viib) , 115R(4) , 20 , 139 , 14 , 10(10B) , 115VF , 115VG , 17(3)(i) , 17(3)(iii) , 28(ii) , 28(va) , 2(24)(iia) , 56(2)(viia) , 2(25A) , 115BBD , 49(2) , 49(2A) , 49(2AA) , 49(2AB) , 49(2E) , 55(2)(b) , 2(22B) , 55(2)(a) , 55(2)(aa) , 48 , 55(2) , 55(2)(ab) , 2(22)(d) , 49(4) , 50C(2) , 51 , 55(1)(b) , 49 , 28 , 45(2) , 115ACA , 112(1) , 2(48) , 2(47) , 2(42A) , 45(1A) , 45(3) , 2(14)(ii) , 45(4) , 45(1) , 45(5) , 45(5)(b) , 45(5)(c ) , 155(16) , 145A(b) , 46 , 46(2) , 55(2)(b)(iii) , 48(ii) , 55 , 50A , 32(1)(i) , 41(2) , 50C , 2(14)(iii) , 45(6) , 46A , 45(2A) , 47A(2) , 47(xiiia) , 49(3) , 47(iv) , 47(v) , 115I , 55A , 10(41) , 54 , 54F , 2(42B) , 2(29B) , 2(29A) , 54EC , 47(xvi) , 2(47)(v) , 2(47)(i) , 2(47)(ii) , 2(47)(iii) , 2(47)(iv) , 47(5) , 2(47)(vi) , 47(xv) , 56 , 50D , 36(1)(iii) , 49(1)(i) , 55(3) , 56(1) , 2(22)(b) , 2(22)(a) , 56(2) , 94(1) , 94(6) , 94(8) , 57 , 56(2)(iii) , 57(ii) , 57(iii) , 57(iia) , 37(1) , 58 , 56(2)(vii)(b) , 56(vii) , 56(viia) , 59 , 43A , 43 , 32(1)(iii) , 38(2) , 32(1)(iia) , 32(2) , 32AC , 33AB , 33AB(4) , 33AB(3) , 33AB(8) , 33ABA , 33ABA(4) , 43(4)(i) , 35(1)(i) , 43(4)(ii) , 35(2)(i) , 35(2B) , 43(4)(iii) , 41(3) , 73(3) , 35(1)(iii) , 35(1)(iia) , 35(2AA) , 35(2AB) , 35(3) , 35ABB , 35ABB(2) , 35AC , 35AC(2) , 35AC(4) , 35AC(5) , 35CCA , 35CCC , 35CCD , 35D(2) , 35D(3) , 34D(3) , 35DDA , 36(1)(i) , 36(1)(ia) , 36(1)(ib) , 36(1)(ii) , 36(1)(iiia) , 36(1)(iv) , 43B , 36(1)(iva) , 36(1)(v) , 36(1)(vi) , 41(4) , 36(1)(viia) , 36(1)(viii) , 36(1)(xii) , 36(1)(xv) , 36(1)(xiv) , 36(1)(xvi) , 35AB , 37(2B) , 40(a)(ia)
```

but I want data  like this:

```
1,2,2(24),2(35),2AB(1),2-IT(i),2(TT)(iii),3,4,6,7(1)(iii)
```

I  also use [natural sort of text and numbers, JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/natural-sort-of-text-and-numbers-javascript) this type all solution but it's not working.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Define rules of your sorting. It is unclear (at least for me) how you compare these strings. Once you do that the implementation should be straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
var uniqueName =  [72A(6) , 72(A)(6A) , 78(1) , 72AB(1) , 79 , 80QQB , 80RRB , 80TTA , 80U , 80CCC , 80CCD , 80CCE , 80CCF , 80CCG , 80D , 80DD , 80DDB , 80E , 80EE , 80G , 92C(4) , 80G(2)(c ) , 80G(5) , 80GG , 80C , 80GGA , 80GGB , 80GGC , 80-IA , 80-IA(4) , 80-IA(4)(ii) , 80-IA(4)(iii) , 80-IA(4)(iv) , 80-IA(4)(v) , 80-IA(5) , 80-IA(4)(i) , 80-IA(12) , 80-IAB , 80-IB , 80-IB(2) , 80-IB(3) , 80-IB(4) , 80-IB(5) , 80-IB(11) , 80-IB(7) , 80-IB(7A) , 80-IB(7B) , 80-IB(8A) , 80-IB(9) , 80-IB(10) , 80-IB(11A) , 80-IB(11B) , 80-IB(11C) , 80-IC , 80-ID , 80-ID(3) , 80-IE , 80JJA , 80LA , 80JJAA , 80P , 56(2)(vii) , 184(2) , 184 , 144 , 184(5) , 185 , 47(xiiib) , 32(1) , 35DDA(4A) , 43(1) , 43(6) , 47A(4) , 49(1) , 49(2AAA) , 72A(6A) , 115JAA , 167C , 36 , 37 , 40(b) , 40A(2) , 187(2) , 115JC , 115JD , 115JEE , 1]
  uniqueName.sort(sortAlphaNum);


var reA = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
var reN = /[^0-9()]/g;
var resN = /[^0-9]/g;
function sortAlphaNum(a,b) {
        var aN = parseInt(a.replace(reN, ""), 10);
        var bN = parseInt(b.replace(reN, ""), 10);
        var a1 = a.indexOf('(');
        var a2 = a.indexOf(')');
        var b1 = b.indexOf('(');
        var b2 = b.indexOf(')');
        if(aN==bN){
            if(a1>-1 && a2>-1 && b1>-1 && b2>-1){
                var str1 = a.substring(a1+1,a2);
                var str2 = b.substring(b1+1,b2);
                var aN1 = parseInt(str1.replace(resN, ""), 10);
                var bN1 = parseInt(str2.replace(resN, ""), 10);
                if(aN1>bN1){
                    return 1;
                }else if(aN1<bN1){
                    return -1;
                }else{
                    var aN2 = str1.replace(reA, "");
                    var bN2 = str2.replace(reA, "");
                    if(aN2>bN2){
                        return 1;
                    }else if(aN2<bN2){
                        return -1;
                    }else{
                        return a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1;

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return aN === bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery sort()

jQuery;

```
 $("#jqSort").html($("#jqSort option").sort(function (a, b) {
     return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
 }))
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/3bAuy/

Comment: This is not correct.
Add <option value="10a">10a</option>

Answer (score 0):

you can do  as follows: first,the first word of old string is as the first word of the new string;then compare between the second word of the old string and the first word of the new string so that you will know which one should be the first of the new string(by the way,you should compare the first letter of them,if the same,compare the second letter.just do like this rule);then compare between the third word of the old string and every word of the new string so that you will know where the third word should be in the new string……,do like this util the last word of the old string,finally,the sorting of the new string is what you want.