# localeCompare with ASCII style lexicographical sorting

Tags: javascript, string, sorting

I was trying what I hoped to be a trivial exercise in coding: sorting Javascript strings with an ASCII style lexicographical order (e.g. numbers before capitalized letters before lowercased letters...).

Here's a snippet:

```
var str1 = "ab";
var str2 = "Ab";
var n = str1.localeCompare(
    str2, "en", {sensitivity: 'variant', caseFirst: "upper"}
);
```

In this case, I would expect `n` to be `1`, but it returns `-1` instead.

From the documentation on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) page:

- the `sensitivity` value set as `variant` would allow differentiating between all base and accented letters, including case
- the `caseFirst` value set as `upper` would force upper-cased letters to compare smaller than lower-cased letters
- the lack of `usage` parametrization would default to `sort`, which would be irrelevant here anyway since I'm specifying `variant`
- the lack of `ignorePunctuation` parametrization would default to `false`

I am assuming the options override the default locale settings, although I couldn't find any specific information on the matter. 
In truth if it defaulted to `en-US` and had priority over the options, then I imagine case would be ignored (e.g. see accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861386/force-localecompare-to-be-case-sensitive)).

What am I doing wrong?

**Notes**

- I am mentioning "ASCII" here for the sole purpose of identifying a sorting order that does not ignore case and sorts uppercase letters before lowercase letters where applicable. I would ultimately employ this for unicode strings as well.
- As suggested by some, this is likely engine-dependent. 
  Replicated with Firefox ESR 52.6.0, and Chromium 64.0.3282.167.

Comment: Running your code, I actually get `1`.

Comment: it is browser dependent which result you get. it works for chrome, but not in edge.

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks, that makes sense. Added browser in notes.

Comment: Now added browser*s* in notes...

Comment: are you looking for a solution which works always? something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260479/javascript-sorting-an-array-like-order-by-in-oracle/33269451#33269451 with with changed cases?

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for the link. Interesting custom sorting, but unfortunately your solution #1 doesn't look like it would be working for me. Firstly it doesn't seem to yield `digit < letter` and from the specifications of the question it won't yield `uppercase letter < lowercase letter` either.

Comment: Note: All strings in JavaScript are Unicode (UTF-16 encoding). Also, while JavaScript does support locales, it does not natively support identifying all digit and letter characters, including by Unicode categories. So, you'd have to use lots of codepoint ranges for that. Google for code generators that help in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're getting `-1`. When I run the exact code you've provided, I get `1`. I only get `-1` when testing with `str1.localeCompare(str2)`. Perhaps make note of [this warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Parameters):

> Implementations are not required to support this property.

If your `sensitivity` is set to `variant`, and your `caseFirst` to `upper`, that's already the default comparison for strings. Locale is typically used for synonymizing character variants. Also, in ASCII and Unicode, uppercase already comes before lowercase. So you just need `-(str1 < str2) || +(str1 > str2)` and avoid the function call altogether:

```js
var str1 = "ab";
var str2 = "Ab";
var a = str1.localeCompare(
    str2, "en", {sensitivity: 'variant', caseFirst: "upper"}
);
var b = -(str1 < str2) || +(str1 > str2);
console.log(a, b);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nina suggests this is browser related. Will try around with different engines - I was expecting my code to be supported by all but that doesn't mean the functionality might differ ultimately I guess... sigh.

Comment: Updated browsers and `var a` is still `-1` for me when I run your code right from the snippet. However weirdly enough your workaround solution does return `1` - investigating a bit more...

Comment: @Mena the "workaround solution", which I'm suggesting as an actual solution and not a browser-specific hack, relies on the specification. It's not weird that it returns `1`, its comparisons are based on the character unicode values.

Comment: my poor choice of words. I am considering using that as it looks like the only reliable solution so far.

Comment: It occurs to me that there actually is a reason for you wanting to use `localeCompare()` though: With the proper support, you're going for the order: `AaBbCcDdEe...` whereas ASCII / Unicode order is `ABCDE... abcde...` e.g. you may not want `Z` < `a`

Comment: actually I **do** want `Z < a` in this instance, hence the problem with `localeCompare` in the first place :) This is mimicking a Java-based sorting algorithm in the back-end where the default comparator will always consider upper-cased letters as less than lower-cased letters amongst others.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a workaround by looking of the case of the letters and use a helper string which reflects the position of the upper and lower letters.

> Helper array before sorting
>
> ```
> index  value
> -----  -----
>    0    a b 
>    1    a  B
>    2     Ab 
>    3     A B
> ```
>
> after sorting
>
> ```
> index  value
> -----  -----
>    3    A B
>    2    Ab 
>    1   a  B
>    0   a b
> ```

```js
var array = ['ab', 'aB', 'Ab', 'AB'],
    mapped = array
        .map((el, i) => ({ index: i, value: [...el].map(c => c === c.toUpperCase() ? ' ' + c : c + ' ').join('') }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value)),
    result = mapped.map(el => array[el.index]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina. That seems to be more cumbersome than Patrick's solution, so ultimately I'd pick his for simplicity.