# Create/manage multidimensional array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am building a chat application using socket.io.

I need to create an array to manage the users connected to each chat room.

To start with I need to store the chat room name, and then in that chat room each user and their status.

```
chat1
     nickname: user1
     status:   admin
     nickname: user2
     status:   none
     nickname: user3
     status:   none
```

I need it to sort the nicknames in alphabetical order when it is created or when a user is added or deleted. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've described isn't a multidimensional array, it's an array of Objects or Maps. Assuming Objects:

```
chat1 = [
     { nickname: 'ethelred',
       status:   'admin'},
     { nickname: 'alfred',
       status:   'none' },
     { nickname: 'canute',
       status:   'none' }
  ]

// This is all that's needed for a very simple sort:
chat1.sort((a,b) => a.nickname > b.nickname)
```

This will sort and give you `[{nickname: 'alfred', status: 'none' }, {nickname: 'canute', status: 'none' }, { nickname: 'ethelred', status: 'admin'}]`

```
// You can continue to transform the data,
// for example, just pull the user nicknames:
chat1.sort((a,b) => a.nickname - b.nickname)
     .map(user => user.nickname)
```

That will sort and then map across the resulting sorted array to give you a list of users in alphabetical order - `['alfred','canute','ethelred']`.

*Note*, this is naïve, you will need better logic in the sort function (what happens with capital letters, numbers, numbers mixed in with letters, *&c*?). But that function is completely isolated. You just write a separate (dumb) function that knows nothing about your chatroom object, and pass that to `sort()` with `a.nickname` and `b.nickname` as the arguments - `chat1.sort(myFunkySortFunction(a.nickname, b.nickname))` (or you inline the logic and don't abstract it, whatever's simplest).

You'll start getting issues if you have a lot of users, as you'll need to run this on every join/leave event. At that point you'll need something a lot more robust.

---

Edit1:

So when a new person joins, they either get a. `.push()`-ed onto the original array, or b. you create a new array with the new person's object. When a person leaves, they either a. get removed from the original array, or b. a new array is created that doesn't include them.

When either of those events happen, you could run the sort function. You need to look at the [`Array.prototype.sort()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). That should literally be the only thing you need.

Note, what I'm suggesting is not very efficient, it will just do the job, and is very simple.

---

Re the function passed to sort, `a.nickname > b.nickname` is not going to work very well. `A-Z` will come before `a-z`. 'Xerxes' will come before 'albert'. You could do:

```
chat1.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.nickname.toLowerCase() > b.nickname.toLowerCase();
})
```

So that would sort that out. But you've still an issue with more complex names: it's worth looking at something robust like described here: [Javascript : natural sort of alphanumerical strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings)

Basically, what you're doing isn't hard: you just need to make sure that in that callback function, you specify that you're grabbing the `nickname` property, otherwise it'll try to sort based on the whole object, and return weird incorrect results.

---

**[very late] Edit2**

I just realised that you asked how to add and remove. Staying on the same (functional) theme as the rest of the above: to add you can use `Array.prototype.concat()` to create a new array that includes the extra user. To remove, `Array.prototype.filter()` will return a new array with a specific user excised.

So add:

```
current = [
  { nickname: 'ethelred',
    status:   'admin'},
  { nickname: 'alfred',
    status:   'none' },
  { nickname: 'canute',
    status:   'none' }
]

current.concat({ nickname: 'offa', status: 'none' })

// [{ nickname: 'ethelred', status: 'admin'}, { nickname: 'alfred', status: 'none'}, { nickname: 'canute', status: 'none'}, { nickname: 'offa', status: 'none'}]
```

To remove:

```
current = [
  { nickname: 'ethelred',
    status:   'admin'},
  { nickname: 'alfred',
    status:   'none' },
  { nickname: 'canute',
    status:   'none' }
]

current.filter({nickname} => nickname !== 'canute')

// [{ nickname: 'ethelred', status: 'admin'}, { nickname: 'alfred', status: 'none'}]
```

Comment: Thanks! What functions do I need to look at to add/remove etc.? i.e. to create as per your example at the top?

Comment: Added an edit the answer rather than adding comments :)

Comment: Just seen now that I didn't really answer your comment properly: added some more info. Read up on Array prototype methods on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype