# Sort the data having combination of letters and digits has value in array of json in javascript

Tags: javascript, natural-sort

How to sort the array of json data having letters and digits?

**JS:**

```
function sortOn(property) {
        return function (a, b) {
            if (a[property] < b[property]) {
                return -1;
            } else if (a[property] > b[property]) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

  var data = [{"id":1,name:"text10"},
              {"id":4,"name":"text1"}, {"id":4,"name":"text19"},     {"id":4,"name":"text2"}, {"id":4,"name":"text20"},
               {"id":5,"name":"book"}];
data.sort(sortOn('name'));
console.log(data);// when I print the JSON getting book,text1,text10..

//But I have to want to show the json as book,text1,text2...
```

Any one can help me how to sort the name thing having both letters and digits

Please find the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d95zt296/) for reference.

Comment: What you're looking for is a _natural_ sort algorithm, which you can find by googling

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : natural sort of alphanumerical strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings)

Comment: Could you send me the any sample code , so that I will apply to my code?

Answer (score 0):

Very simplistic implementation. Sort on either the number in the name and if it doesn't exist, use the full name. Could be sped up by caching the parseInt || name comparison.

```
var result = data.sort(function ( a, b ) {
    var first = parseInt(/\d+/g.exec(a.name), 10) || a.name,
        second = parseInt(/\d+/g.exec(b.name), 10) || b.name;
    if (first > second) return 1;
    else if (first === second) return 0;
    else return -1;
    return -1
});
```

Comment: I tried the with above code, still am getting book,text1,text10.

Comment: it works only if the number is the first art of the string.

Comment: Whoops, I misread the required output. Updated the code with a regex that will grab the numbers from the string. I get "book, text1, text2, text10, ..." etc now.