# Natural-sorting json response with case sensitive in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

Need to perform natural sorting using javaScript keeping uppercase before lowercase, I have created plunker for detailed understanding.

I have used natural sorter function answered in the previous post given by [kennebec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80860/kennebec) ([Javascript : natural sort of alphanumerical strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings))

Plunker: [plnkr.co/edit/Ls2jRRpHJcOhHhkFl8dC?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ls2jRRpHJcOhHhkFl8dC?p=preview)

```
function compare(x, y) {     
      //naturalSorter should return job column sorting as A (uppercase), a(lowercase), A13(alphanum), A13(alphanum), A14(alphanum)
                return naturalSorter(x, y);               
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `'a' < 'b' && 'A' < 'a'` Run this in your console.  It will return *true*.  Uppercase is already naturally less than lowercase.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: yes! but even when we try without converting x and y to lowercase, result are not as expected. please see the plunker.

Comment: Updated plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/Ls2jRRpHJcOhHhkFl8dC?p=preview)

Comment: The problem is not the sorter then.  Unfortunately, I can't tell you anything more than that.  Your plunker example is missing the code in your question, so I can't perform a test to see how you're applying the sort.  Update your plunkr or provide a bare-bones example in your question proving that it sorts incorrectly using the naturalSorter.

Comment: Here is the updated plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/Ls2jRRpHJcOhHhkFl8dC?p=preview

Comment: That is the same link as the one above...

Comment: I was under the impression that you wanted your error fixed.  Apparently, I was grossly mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do the toLowerCase, just `return naturalSorter(x, y)` should sort in the correct order

Comment: No it did not help me :-(  the result are not correctly sorted. Kindly check the plunker. Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ls2jRRpHJcOhHhkFl8dC?p=preview