# Angular natural sort array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, natural-sort

I'm fairly new to Angular so maybe I'm just searching for the wrong thing, but I can't seem to find an easy answer to this anywhere.

Let's say I have an array of objects:

```
[
  {Label: "UDP 128B Flood", ...},
  {Label: "UDP 512B Flood", ...},
  {Label: "UPD 1514B Flood",...},
  {Label: "HTTP Excessive GET",...} 
]
```

This is array is being displayed as the options in a dropdown:

```
<option *ngFor="let profile of Profiles" [value]="profile.Label">{{profile.Label}}</option>
```

I want to sort these objects to make sure they show up in alphanumeric order.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function

```js
let sorted = [
  {Label: "UDP 128B Flood"},
  {Label: "UDP 512B Flood"},
  {Label: "UDP 1514B Flood"},
  {Label: "HTTP Excessive GET"} 
].sort((a, b) => a.Label.localeCompare(b.Label));

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: This is very close, but "UDP 1514B Flood" is sorted in front of "UDP 512B Flood"

Comment: That's because it's actually "UPD 1514B". EDIT: I've changed it to UDP for you, so it now sorts in the order you'd expect

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript : natural sort of alphanumerical strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings)

Found the answer from this thread.

```
profiles.sort((as, bs) => {
var a: any, b: any, a1: number, b1: number, i= 0, n: number , L,
    rx=/(\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?)|([^\d.]+)|(\.\D+)|(\.$)/g;
if(as.Label=== bs.Label) return 0;
a= as.Label.toLowerCase().match(rx);
b= bs.Label.toLowerCase().match(rx);
L= a.length;
while(i<L){
    if(!b[i]) return 1;
    a1= a[i],
        b1= b[i++];
    if(a1!== b1){
        n= a1-b1;
        if(!isNaN(n)) return n;
        return a1>b1? 1:-1;
    }
}
return b[i]? -1:0;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

> Try this, hope this would help.

```
var array=[
  {Label: "UDP 128B Flood", ...},
  {Label: "UDP 512B Flood", ...},
  {Label: "UPD 1514B Flood",...},
  {Label: "HTTP Excessive GET",...} 
]
array.sort(this.sortArray);
sortArray(){ if(b.Label.toString().toLowerCase() <a.Label.toString().toLowerCase()) { return -1; }
if(b.Label.toString().toLowerCase() >a.Label.toString().toLowerCase()) { return 1; } }
```