# Sort array of strings with negative and positive numbers

Tags: javascript

Firstly I could not find a question addressing the whole issue.

I used to compare arrays like this:

```
array.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'})
})
```

But I realized it does not work on an array like `['a', 'A', 'B', -1.50', '0', '1.50', '-2', '2']`.

The expected output would be: `['-2', '-1.50', '0', '1.50', '2', 'A', 'a', 'B']`.

I have some dirty ideas to achieve it. But maybe there is a clean and easy way.

Comment: I'm not sure, what is the `field` argument intended to do?

Comment: Given an array of objects, I parameterized the attribute of the object, so that I won't write a sort method for different attributes.

Comment: I guess it is not much relevant to the question so removed it to avoid confusion.

Comment: why do you need *`{numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'}`*?

Comment: @NinaScholz https://stackoverflow.com/a/38641281/6469020

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could prepend the comparison by taking the delta of the wanted properties. This saves the order for numerical values.

```js
console.log(
    ['a', 'A', 'B', '-1.50', '0', '1.50', '-2', '2', 'D']
        .sort((a, b) => a - b || a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {sensitivity: 'base'}))
);
```

`numeric: true` option can be omitted for there won't be two numbers to compare at the left hand side of the expression.

Comment: I guess in this case we already look whether it is number or not, so it would be better if we omit `numeric: true` option for performance.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `isNaN` method in order to check if you compare numerical strings. If yes, `localeCompare` is not recommended , you need to use `Number(a) - Number(b)`

```js
array = ['a', 'A', 'B','-1.50', '0', '1.50', '-2', '2']
array.sort((a, b) => {
  return !isNaN(a) && !isNaN(b) ? Number(a)-Number(b) : a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { sensitivity: 'base'});
})
    
console.log(array);
```

Since in Javascript the `-` operator is defined only for numeric subtraction, the operands will be coerced to `Number`. So you could simply use:

```
array.sort((a, b) => {
  return a - b || a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { sensitivity: 'base'});
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const customSort = (array) => {
    return array.sort((a, b) => {

        let r = /^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/;

        if (r.test(a) && r.test(b))
        {
            return a - b;
        }

        return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'})
    })
}

console.log(customSort(['a', 'A', 'B', '-1.50', '0', '1.50', '-2', '2']));
// => [ '-2', '-1.50', '0', '1.50', '2', 'a', 'A', 'B' ]
```