# sorting a javascript array with numbers stored as text

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sorted my `array`. I'm trying to sort the blocks by the `[2]` entry in each of the square brackets. So the 15th should be at the top and the 8th should be second and so on.

I've tried using.

```
var sorted = data.sort(function(a,b){return b[2]-a[2]});
console.log(sorted);
```

and

```
data.sort(function(a,b){return b[2]-a[2]});
console.log(sorted);
```

but this didn't work. Is it because the numbers are stored as text? if so i've tried par

```
data.sort(function(a,b){return parseFloat(b[2])-parseFloat(a[2])});
console.log(sorted);
```

and this didn't work either.

```
0:(2) ["HDR", "GENERATION BY FUEL TYPE CURRENT Last Updated At 20180719150500"]
1:(2) ["FTR", "14"]
2:(8) ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "OCGT", "0", "0.0", "0", "0.0", "0", "0.0"]
3:(8) ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "OIL", "0", "0.0", "0", "0.0", "0", "0.0"]
4:(8) ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "COAL", "947", "3.0", "900", "2.9", "15144", "2.2"]
5:(8) ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "NUCLEAR", "6407", "20.4", "6477", "20.8", "158268", "22.5"]
6:(8) ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "WIND", "1710", "5.4", "1678", "5.4", "11903", "1.7"]
7:(8) ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "PS", "165", "0.5", "174", "0.6", "6854", "1.0"]
8:(8) ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "CCGT", "17355", "55.2", "17144", "55.1", "382043", "54.3"]
9:(8) ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "OTHER", "59", "0.2", "59", "0.2", "1406", "0.2"]
10:(8) ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "INTFR", "1998", "6.4", "1998", "6.4", "47363", "6.7"]
11:(8) ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "INTIRL", "0", "0.0", "0", "0.0", "1960", "0.3"]
12:(8) ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "INTNED", "1001", "3.2", "1000", "3.2", "23097", "3.3"]
13:(8) ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "INTEW", "0", "0.0", "0", "0.0", "4803", "0.7"]
14:(8) ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "BIOMASS", "1649", "5.2", "1621", "5.2", "48031", "6.8"]
15:(7) ["TOTAL", "31448", "100.0", "31128", "100.0", "703547", "100.0"]
16:(8) ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "NPSHYD", "157", "0.5", "77", "0.2", "2675", "0.4"]
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your missing the `s` in `pareFloat`. Should be `parseFloat`.

Comment: your array at index 1 is not having an element at index 2. what about that?

Comment: Could you also provide the original array before sorting?

Comment: You are mixing different types of records. You need to clean your data first and then sort them. Items at indexes 1 and 15 are obviously just some aggregations and the item at index 0 is some label.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn this is the unsorted data. the things i have tried don't make a difference

Comment: `0:(2)` and the rest aren't valid values in an array. Please convert it to a valid array.

Comment: `const result = data.filter((item) => Number.isFinite(parseFloat(item[2]))).sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b[2]) - parseFloat(a[2]))` - this works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a huge value `Infinity` for sorting non given items to top.

[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) expects a numerical value of smaller than zero, zero or greater than zero for the wanted order. To get this result, you could take for simple numbers the delta of it.

```
b - a // sorts descending
```

For a not used index of the array, you could check it with [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) and take a value which shifts or keeps the item at the actual place on top by using a greater value then usually taken as number in the array, which is [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity).

```js
var data = [["HDR", "GENERATION BY FUEL TYPE CURRENT Last Updated At 20180719150500"], ["FTR", "14"], ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "OCGT", "0", "0.0", "0", "0.0", "0", "0.0"], ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "OIL", "0", "0.0", "0", "0.0", "0", "0.0"], ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "COAL", "947", "3.0", "900", "2.9", "15144", "2.2"], ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "NUCLEAR", "6407", "20.4", "6477", "20.8", "158268", "22.5"], ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "WIND", "1710", "5.4", "1678", "5.4", "11903", "1.7"], ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "PS", "165", "0.5", "174", "0.6", "6854", "1.0"], ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "CCGT", "17355", "55.2", "17144", "55.1", "382043", "54.3"], ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "OTHER", "59", "0.2", "59", "0.2", "1406", "0.2"], ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "INTFR", "1998", "6.4", "1998", "6.4", "47363", "6.7"], ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "INTIRL", "0", "0.0", "0", "0.0", "1960", "0.3"], ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "INTNED", "1001", "3.2", "1000", "3.2", "23097", "3.3"], ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "INTEW", "0", "0.0", "0", "0.0", "4803", "0.7"], ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "BIOMASS", "1649", "5.2", "1621", "5.2", "48031", "6.8"], ["TOTAL", "31448", "100.0", "31128", "100.0", "703547", "100.0"], ["FUELINSTHHCUR", "NPSHYD", "157", "0.5", "77", "0.2", "2675", "0.4"]];

data.sort((a, b) => (2 in b ? b[2] : Infinity) - (2 in a ? a[2] : Infinity));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: could you possibly explain what this is doing to sort the data?

Answer (score 1):

This would do your trick

```js
var collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {
  numeric: true,
  sensitivity: 'base'
});
var myArray = ['1_Document', '11_Document', '2_Document'];
console.log(myArray.sort(collator.compare));
```

Reference: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38641281/7849868)

Comment: This kind of works but it's sorting on the [1] entry of each array. I need to sort from the [2] of each array from largest to smallest?