# How to sort data which mix text and number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have a data which will show as the table and using orderBy(lodash) to sort data but it's not working as I want.

Now, I code as
`const data = orderBy(realData, ['name'], ['asc'])`

Here's my data 
input:
`[{name: 'A1'},{name:'A2'},{name: 'A21'},{name:'B10'},{name: 'A100'},{name:'A22'},{name: 'B32'},{name:'A3'}]`

The issue is 'orderBy' sort data as it text(ASCII sorting)
current output:
`[{name: 'A1'},{name: 'A100'},{name:'A2'},{name: 'A21'},{name:'A22'},{name:'A3'},{name:'B10'},{name: 'B32'}]`

but I would like the data output like this

`[{name: 'A1'},{name:'A2'},{name:'A3'},{name: 'A21'},{name:'A22'},{name: 'A100'},{name:'B10'},{name: 'B32'}]`

If anyone have any suggestion, please help.

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : natural sort of alphanumerical strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `string#localeCompare` callback while sorting an array. To numerically sort the array use `numeric` property.

```js
let data = [{name: 'A1'},{name: 'A100'},{name:'A2'},{name: 'A21'},{name:'A22'},{name:'A3'},{name:'B10'},{name: 'B32'}];
data.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, {numeric: true}));
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy to understand way is like this:

```
data.sort((a, b) => {
  const listA = a.name.trim().split('');
  const listB = b.name.trim().split('');

  const categoryA = listA.splice(0, 1);
  const categoryB = listB.splice(0, 1);

  const numberA = listA.join('');
  const numberB = listB.join('');

  if (categoryA > categoryB) return 1;
  if (categoryA < categoryB) return -1;

  return numberA - numberB;
});
```