# Sorting alphanumeric field using lodash orderby

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash, ecmascript-5

I am having problems sorting array of objects of this format

```
const arr = [
  { name: "test_1", age: 15 },
  { name: "test_11", age: 20 },
  { name: "test_12", age: 34 },
  { name: "test_2", age: 35 },
  { name: "test", age: 39 },
  { name: "example", age: 35 },
];
```

With the code that I have tried, it sorts based on string, hence I am getting wrong output. Can someone help me out with this using lodash

```
import orderby from "lodash.orderby";
const arr = [
  { name: "test_1", age: 15 },
  { name: "test_11", age: 20 },
  { name: "test_12", age: 34 },
  { name: "test_2", age: 35 }
];

function sortArr(field, order) {
  const result = orderby(
    arr,
    [
      (item) =>
        typeof item[field] === "string"
          ? item[field].toLocaleLowerCase()
          : item[field]
    ],
    order
  );
  return result;
}
console.log(sortArr("name", "asc"));
```

Output that I am expecting, test_1 test_2 test_11 test_12

Help wil be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort data which mix text and number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324302/how-to-sort-data-which-mix-text-and-number)

Comment: What you want is often called "natural sort" (I don't know if Lodash uses that term).

Answer (score 0):

If using `lodash` isn't a requirement here, you could use JavaScript's built in [`array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) like this:

```js
arr.sort(
    (a, b) =>
        parseInt(a.name.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")) -
        parseInt(b.name.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""))
);
```

**Demo:**

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "test_1", age: 15 },
  { name: "test_11", age: 20 },
  { name: "test_12", age: 34 },
  { name: "test_2", age: 35 },
  {name: "test^34", age: 33},
  {name: "13&&test", age: 27},
];

let sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.name.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")) - parseInt(b.name.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")))

console.log(sorted)
```

---

****If `lodash` is a requirement you can use `lodash`'s [`_.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy), like this:****

```js
_.sortBy(arr, [(a) => _.toNumber(_.replace(a.name, /[^0-9]/g, ""))])
```

**Demo:**

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "test_1", age: 15 },
  { name: "test_11", age: 20 },
  { name: "test_12", age: 34 },
  { name: "test_2", age: 35 },
  { name: "8-test", age: 23 },
];

let sorted = _.sortBy(arr, [(a) => _.toNumber(_.replace(a.name, /[^0-9]/g, ""))])

console.log(sorted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.19/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it will not always be strings with _?just random strings

Comment: @li97 I've made an edit to my post, this will sort the strings regardless of where the numbers appear.

Comment: thanks for the edit. looking for something in lodash

Comment: @li97 I've made an edit to the second half of my post, you can use lodash's _.sortBy in a similar way.