# How to sort object of array with external condition and the property of object?

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I am using `lodash.orderBy` method and try to sort data like this:

I have two external sort conditions: `condition1` and `condition2`

```js
const condition1 = 'aa';
const condition2 = 'b';

const datas = [
  { f1: 'aaa', f2: 'b', f3: '2019-01-01' },
  { f1: 'a', f2: 'b', f3: '2019-01-02' },
  { f1: 'a', f2: 'c', f3: '2019-01-08' },
  { f1: 'aa', f2: 'b', f3: '2019-01-08' },
  { f1: 'aa', f2: 'b', f3: '2019-01-09' },
  { f1: 'aa', f2: 'c', f3: '2019-01-07' },
  { f1: 'xxx', f2: 'c', f3: '2019-01-03' },
  { f1: 't', f2: 'd', f3: '2019-01-04' },
  { f1: 'a', f2: 'd', f3: '2019-01-01' },
  { f1: 'aa', f2: 'd', f3: '2019-01-02' },
];
```

I expect data sorted like this:

```js
  const expect = [
          { f1: 'aa', f2: 'b', f3: '2019-01-09' },
          { f1: 'aa', f2: 'b', f3: '2019-01-08' },
          { f1: 'aa', f2: 'c', f3: '2019-01-07' },
          { f1: 'aa', f2: 'd', f3: '2019-01-02' },
          { f1: 'a', f2: 'b', f3: '2019-01-02' },
          { f1: 'aaa', f2: 'b', f3: '2019-01-01' },
          { f1: 'a', f2: 'c', f3: '2019-01-08' },
          { f1: 't', f2: 'd', f3: '2019-01-04' },
          { f1: 'xxx', f2: 'c', f3: '2019-01-03' },
          { f1: 'a', f2: 'd', f3: '2019-01-01' },
        ];
```

The sorting rule is:

1. sort by `f1` if the value of `f1` equal with `condition1` - priority 1
2. sort by `f2` if `f1` is same, the value of `f2` should equal with `condition2` - priority 2
3. sort by `f3`(desc) when `f1` and `f2` are same - priority 3

priority 1 is the highest.

Can't figure it out. Thanks for your help. `lodash.orderBy` and `sort` method of javascript, both of these solutions are ok.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure I fully understand your problem, but it looks to me as if the JavaScript sort function combined with a custom sort function is all you need.

Something like this (not tested) code:

```
datas.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.f1 === condition1) {
    return a.f1.localeCompare(b.f1);
  } else if (a.f2 === condition2) {
    return a.f2.localeCompare(b.f2);
  } else {
    return a.f3.localeCompare(b.f3);
  }
});
```

Comment: If performance is an issue, you may want to create a collator. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38641281/2095953

Comment: Thanks. But the unit test doesn't pass.  I improve my question.

Comment: @slideshowp2 I see. This only makes the If a little more complicated and instead of just returning from the string compare, just must go a level deeper if the strings are the same and do the next if.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it looks like very verbose.

```js
it('t1', () => {
        const goal = 'aa';
        const channelNme = 'b';

        const datas = [
          { goal: 'aaa', channelNme: 'b', date: '2019-01-01' },
          { goal: 'a', channelNme: 'b', date: '2019-01-02' },
          { goal: 'a', channelNme: 'c', date: '2019-01-08' },
          { goal: 'aa', channelNme: 'b', date: '2019-01-08' },
          { goal: 'aa', channelNme: 'b', date: '2019-01-09' },
          { goal: 'aa', channelNme: 'c', date: '2019-01-07' },
          { goal: 'xxx', channelNme: 'c', date: '2019-01-03' },
          { goal: 't', channelNme: 'd', date: '2019-01-04' },
          { goal: 'a', channelNme: 'd', date: '2019-01-01' },
          { goal: 'aa', channelNme: 'd', date: '2019-01-02' },
        ];

        const aa = datas.filter(d => d.goal === goal).sort(sortByDateDesc);
        const notAa = datas.filter(d => d.goal !== goal).sort(sortByDateDesc);
        const notAaB = notAa.filter(d => d.channelNme === channelNme).sort(sortByDateDesc);
        const notAaNotB = notAa.filter(d => d.channelNme !== channelNme).sort(sortByDateDesc);

        const actualValue = [...aa, ...notAaB, ...notAaNotB];

        function sortByDateDesc(a, b) {
          return new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime();
        }

        const expectValue = [
          { goal: 'aa', channelNme: 'b', date: '2019-01-09' },
          { goal: 'aa', channelNme: 'b', date: '2019-01-08' },
          { goal: 'aa', channelNme: 'c', date: '2019-01-07' },
          { goal: 'aa', channelNme: 'd', date: '2019-01-02' },
          { goal: 'a', channelNme: 'b', date: '2019-01-02' },
          { goal: 'aaa', channelNme: 'b', date: '2019-01-01' },
          { goal: 'a', channelNme: 'c', date: '2019-01-08' },
          { goal: 't', channelNme: 'd', date: '2019-01-04' },
          { goal: 'xxx', channelNme: 'c', date: '2019-01-03' },
          { goal: 'a', channelNme: 'd', date: '2019-01-01' },
        ];
        console.log(`actualValue: ${JSON.stringify(actualValue, null, 2)}`);
        expect(actualValue).toEqual(expectValue);
      });
```

This unit test passed. Hope there is a better way.