# How to sort items of array first with letter then with number?

Tags: javascript

I have this array

```
const a = ['s2', 'sb', 's5', 's1', 'sc', 's3', 's4']
```

After sort I want to this result:

```
['sb', 'sc', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5']
```

I tried use sort() but didnt work

Comment: Hi @newpluser! Can you share some of the code you've tried and explain why that didn't work?

Comment: Do your strings always have length 2? What about `s10`? How should it be sorted? Please provide some edge cases.

Comment: @trincot no, s10 may exists, if s10 exists then for examlple should be ['sb', ...., 's5', 's10']

Comment: I tried sort() function

Comment: You didn't answer how `s10` should be sorted with the rest. Please provide some edge cases.

Comment: @trincot sorry, I have edited my comment

Comment: That is a mix of [natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings) and a requirement that digits should come after letters. This is going to be cumbersome. Why do you want to deviate from the standard?

Comment: @trincot its not my idea :D 'sb' and 'sc' should be always on the begin of array, rest in numer order

Comment: How complicated can these strings be? Can they be 100 characters long? What is the format? It might be easier to solve for a certain pattern than for the general case. Could the strings be *anything*? What about punctuation, non-latin, ...

Answer (score 0):

use `String.match` to get the chars after `s`, if the chars are numbers use `a-b` to sort else use `localeCompare`.

```js
const a = ["s2","sb","s5","s1","sc","s3","s4","s100","s10","sz","san"];
a.sort(
  (a, b) => (a.match(/s(\d*)/)[1] - b.match(/s(\d*)/)[1]) || a.localeCompare(b)
);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: The title of the question mentions letters and numbers, not 's' character specifically.

Comment: @mutil wordplay :) , but I considered all.

Comment: Array `['y1, 'za']` will throw `TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`.

Comment: where these come from? I think OP will have all elements starting with `s` else it won't make any sense.

Comment: As I said, the title is `... first with letter then with number`, strings starting with 's' may only be the example.

Comment: ohh, let OP confirm this rather assuming. I will update if he does not want this.

Answer (score 0):

You can initially sort with localeCompare, and then by testing if number exists:

```
const a = ['s2', 'sb', 's5', 's1', 'sc', 's3', 's4', 's10', 'sa', 'sza', 's200', 's12', 's113'];
a.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en', { numeric: true }))
 .sort((x, y) => (/[0-9]/g).test(x) - (/[0-9]/g).test(y));

console.log(a);
// ["sa", "sb", "sc", "sza", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s10", "s12", "s113", "s200"]
```

Comment: second sort will mess up the prior sorted data, as it just moves non alphanumeric first, whichever comes last goes first in merge sort but not in order. try with more data as `['s2', 'sb', 's5', 's1', 'sc', 's3', 's4', 's10', 'sa', 'sza', 's200', "s12", "s113"]`

Comment: @AZ_, I don't get it, what is the expected output with the array you mentioned? I get the exact same results as with your solution, except this one also works with first character other than 's'.