# Order array alphanumercially and with a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to reorder an array by two conditions. Making sure that `Pos 10` goes after single digits and that it follows a specific order after that.

I tried to give priority to the string that includes `first` but then if I want to order alphanumerically it resets A to the top. How could I optain the expected result?

```js
const arr = [
  'Pos 10 second',
  'Pos 10 A third',
  'Pos 10 first',
  'Pos 1 second',
  'Pos 1 A third',
  'Pos 1 first',
  'Pos 2 second',
  'Pos 2 A third',
  'Pos 2 first',
]

const res = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.includes('first')) {
    return -1
  } else {
    return 1
  }
  
}).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en', { numeric: true}))

console.log(res)

/* Expected output
[
  'Pos 1 first',
  'Pos 1 second',
  'Pos 1 A third',
  'Pos 2 first',
  'Pos 2 second',
  'Pos 2 A third',
  'Pos 10 first',
  'Pos 10 second',
  'Pos 10 A third'
] */
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings

Comment: you need to keep a list of priority of words and give them a number and use that in your sort algorithm

Comment: @HDM91 I know but how to do both, order by condition and by localcompare, can you reproduce the expected results?

Comment: how about moving locale compare inside first sort ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second sort use `match` on numbers within the string value, converted to `Number`.

```js
const sorted = [
    'Pos 10 second',
    'Pos 10 A third',
    'Pos 10 first',
    'Pos 1 second',
    'Pos 1 A third',
    'Pos 1 first',
    'Pos 2 second',
    'Pos 2 A third',
    'Pos 2 first',
  ]
  .sort((a, b) => a.includes(`first`) ? -1 : 1)
  .sort((a, b) => +a.match(/\d+/) - +b.match(/\d+/));
document.querySelector(`pre`).textContent = 
  JSON.stringify(sorted, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: @Kooilnc Thanks, but the expected result should have `A third` below `second`

Comment: Actually I run just the two sorts and works perfect