# JS: Sequence files not being read in the correct order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following script which reads in all images from a directory and create a GIF.

```js
async function createGif(algorithm) {
  return new Promise(async resolve1 => {
    const files = await promisify(readdir)(imagesFolder)

    // Bunch of other things
    // Happening here

    // draw an image for each file and add frame to encoder
    for (const file of files) {
      await new Promise(resolve3 => {
        const image = new Image()
        console.log(`reading ${file}`)
        image.onload = () => {
          ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
          encoder.addFrame(ctx)
          resolve3()
        }
        image.src = path.join(imagesFolder, file)
      })
    }
  })
}
```

The images are of the pattern: `image1`,`image2`,`image3`,...`image30`.

However, the files are being read in this order when I check the console:

```
reading screenshot1.png
reading screenshot10.png
reading screenshot11.png
reading screenshot12.png
reading screenshot13.png
reading screenshot14.png
reading screenshot15.png
reading screenshot16.png
reading screenshot17.png
reading screenshot18.png
reading screenshot19.png
reading screenshot2.png
reading screenshot20.png
```

Why is it skipping from `screenshot1` to `screenshot10`? It should be reading the files in the correct order in which they are in the directory. Like this:

```js
reading screenshot1.png
reading screenshot2.png
reading screenshot3.png
...
reading screenshot10.png
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should drop the line `return new Promise(async resolve1 => {`, it does nothing useful

Comment: Who says that readdir gives you the files in the order you want?  You shouldn't be relying on a strict ordering when coming from readdir.  If you want them sorted some particular way, then sort them before processing them.

Comment: This is how `readdir` returns them. Note they are in the absolutely correct lexicographical order. Or would you expect `file b` to come before `file ab`?

Comment: "*Why is it skipping from screenshot1 to screenshot10?*" - because that's the normal lexical sort order. "*It should be reading the files in the correct order in which they are in the directory.*" - they *are* in that order in the directory (or, in no order at all). It just might be that whatever file manager you are using does use a natural sort to display its list of files. If you care about the order in which you load them, [sort the array yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2802341/1048572).

Comment: As a good practice, always sort an array if you require exact order for some operation. Never take the order of an array coming from any source for granted.

Comment: Just tested it and in windows file are sorted by natural sort. 001,1, 2, 3, 011, 20