# javascript sort list of objects by string containing letters and numbers

Tags: javascript, string, sorting, object

I am trying to sort a list of objects by a string which is the filename for a song, sometimes the filename includes numbers and letters, but every sorting method I've tried does not sort the filenames in an order you you would expect, such as in my example below, the expected output is:

```
Track 1
Track 2
Track 10
```

but it gets sorted incorrectly as:

```
Track 1
Track 10
Track 2
```

```js
var inputFiles=[
  {
    'name':'Track 1.wav'
  },
  {
    'name':'Track 2.wav'
  },
  {
    'name':'Track 10.wav'
  },
]


      console.log('sort audio files by title: ', inputFiles)
      let sortedAudio = inputFiles.sort(function(a, b) {
        var textA = a['name'].toUpperCase(); 
        var textB = b['name'].toUpperCase();
        return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
      });
      console.log('sortedAudio=',sortedAudio)
```

Comment: This is the so-called [natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing strings with `textA < textB` will give you results according to the lexiographic order of each character - in which case `1 10 2` is the correct ordering. Compare the differences of the numbers instead of doing a string comparison, for which you'll have to extract only the numeric portion of the string. `-` can be used, which will convert each side to a number first.

```js
var inputFiles = [{
    'name': 'Track 1.wav'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Track 2.wav'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Track 10.wav'
  },
]


console.log('sort audio files by title: ', inputFiles);
inputFiles.sort((a, b) => a.name.match(/\d+/)[0] - b.name.match(/\d+/)[0]);
console.log('sortedAudio=', inputFiles);
```

Comment: Just don't use on a list of tracks that don't *all* have track numbers in them.

Answer (score 0):

[`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) can handle numbers for you if you [set the `numeric` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#using_options). Remember to [check if the current browser supports `options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#check_browser_support_for_extended_arguments) and fall back to an approach like [CertainPerformance's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71119828/14956277) if it does not.

```js
var inputFiles = [
  { 'name': 'Track 10.wav' },
  { 'name': 'Track 1.wav' },
  { 'name': 'Track 2.wav' },
  { 'name': 'Track 7.wav' },
  { 'name': 'Unknown Track.wav' },
  { 'name': 'Track 4.wav' },
  { 'name': 'Track 100.wav' },
  { 'name': 'Track 13.wav' },
  { 'name': 'Track 20.wav' },
  { 'name': 'Unknown Track.wav' }
];

const sortedAudio = inputFiles.sort((a,b) => 
  a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, { numeric: true }));

console.log('sortedAudio: ', sortedAudio);
```