# Natural sort of alphanumerical strings in JavaScript (excluding hexadecimal)

Tags: javascript, sorting, hex, natural-sort

I'm looking for an efficient way to sort a list of Alphanumeric labels but ignoring to sort the hexadecimal values like below.

```
arr = [
  "a_19",
  "a_2",
  "b_645500",
  "b_6d4500"
]
```

I've read the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings-in-javascript)

Using { numeric: true } will result in bad sort between hexadecimal values not the shown string label

```
arrNumeric = [
  "a_2",
  "a_19",
  "b_6d4500",
  "b_645500"
]
```

Removing numeric flag will cause bad sort between "a_19" and "a_2".

```
arrNonNumeric = [
  "a_19",
  "a_2",
  "b_645500",
  "b_6d4500"
]
```

the desired sorted array is:

```
arrSorted = [
  "a_2",
  "a_19",
  "b_645500",
  "b_6d4500"
]
```

please note that it's possible to not use (_) in the labels to split each label based on this specific character to extract the non-numeric part

Comment: Which are the "hexadecimal" values?

Comment: This needs a whole lot more specifications. What if `9_99` is in the list? What happens if some don't have `_`? What if multiple `_`? What does "ignoring to sort" mean? That original relative order must be maintained? ...etc, ...etc.

Comment: exactly that's why I mentioned it's possible to have any combination and it should not be split by (_). hexadecimal values are the 645500 and 6d4500 in this example. so IntlCollator compares this part as it's numerical value not the shown string.

Comment: and you'll never have 6 digit decimal numbers?

Comment: So is any clarification coming what should happen in all those cases? Let me continue... What about `c_60_da`, `d_fghi`, `9dabc`, ....

Comment: voting to close for clarity

Comment: all these options are valid, there is no limitation for the user to choose the label, but the default label has always some hexadecimal value in it and that's when the {numeric: true} fails to sort that as a natural string not it's hex value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 compare functions with `Intl.Collator` and use them conditionally based on whether the both compared strings are numbers or not (test with a regexp).

Note that in your particular case it's not possible to distinguish a hex number consisting of 6 digits with an integer of 6 digits.

So that's why here's a regular expression `/\D\d{1,5}$|\D\d{7,}$/` which treats a 6 digit number as a hex value and compares it as a string. As the OP wanted the delimiter is any non-digit character.

We also have problems with the number/hex delimiter. Assuming that's not a digit (`\D`) we need to check whether a potential number is not a hex (since for example `d` inside a hex could act as a number delimiter).
Thus we should also do a negative check of a number against a hex string.

To test more accurately I've added `b_55` so it would be sorted against hex's with the `b_` prefix:

```js
const arr = [
  "a_19",
  "a_2",
  "b_645500",
  "b_55",
  "b_6d4500",
];

const compare = [Intl.Collator('en').compare, Intl.Collator('en', {numeric:true}).compare];

const isNum = /\D\d{1,5}$|\D\d{7,}$/; // test number
const isHex = /\D[0-9a-f]{6}$/; // test hex

arr.sort((a, b, isNumA = isNum.test(a) && !isHex.test(a) , isNumB = isNum.test(b) && !isHex.test(b)) => 
  compare[+(isNumA && isNumB)](a, b));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: but `19` is a hex value

Comment: @pilchard i think in the OP's case a hex is a 6 char string with hex allowed chars

Comment: this also doesn't sort the hexadecimal numbers in numeric order (it will sort `6d5500` before `645500`)

Comment: @pilchard fixed... it required a lot of tweaks, lost sorting temporarily

Comment: @pilchard also added a non-digit delimiter to the regex to separate the number from the rest

Comment: Thanks!
This is exactly what I was looking for :)
Sorry, I've lost my access to my main account and I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer!

Comment: @BoJackMorse i've added an extra regex to make the sorting more precise, added the explanation to the answer

Comment: Thanks, @AlexanderNenashev, I was going to add this test case:
[ "420b0298", "5a810298", "27810298", "15810298"], which was failing with the previous solution.
Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split on the `_` (underscore) and compare the left values first. If they are the same, check the right values. You need to determine the "type" of the value. I created a simple function called `valueType` that determines if a given string is a decimal (`dec`), hexadecimal (`hex`), or a string (`str`).

Note that this is ad-hoc and you should denote hex values with `0x6d450` (prefixed with `0x`).

```js
const valueType = (v) =>
  /^\d+$/.test(v) ? 'dec' : /^[a-f0-9]+$/.test(v) ? 'hex' : 'str';

const valueComparator = (a, b) => {
  const at = valueType(a), bt = valueType(b);
  if (bt !== 'dec' && at === 'dec') return -1; // ^a
  if (at !== 'dec' && bt === 'dec') return 1; // ^b
  return +a - +b; // Normal integer comparison
}

// Compare left and right values
const customComparator = (a, b) => {
  const [ax, ay] = a.split('_'), [bx, by] = b.split('_');
  return ax.localeCompare(bx) || valueComparator(ay, by);
}

const arr = [
  'a_19',
  'a_2',
  'b_64550',
  'b_6d450',
];

console.log([...arr].sort(customComparator));
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to not split based on any specific character and extract the hex part? because the user can set the label using all kinds of characters and it's possible also to use the default value which is the hex combination